# Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?

Tags: debate, faq, respostas, hyperlinks

No Meta StackOverflow, esse assunto já rendeu muita discussão. Os próprios moderadores divergem quanto a flags em respostas que contenham somente links e nada (ou pouco) mais.

Acho muito importante termos esta discussão aqui, pois esse tipo de resposta já está aparecendo.

Um exemplo em: [Como exibir um vídeo do YouTube em um Panel no ExtJS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63/como-exibir-um-video-do-youtube-em-um-panel-no-extjs)

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Notei que esse tipo de resposta está bastante comum nesse início de beta público. Sugiro orientarmos novos usuários com um comentário (adaptado dos do @bigown) e link para cá: "Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow! Respostas que contém \[apenas links\](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42) não sobrevivem ao tempo. Você pode elaborar sua resposta aqui, por exemplo incluindo citações e/ou trechos de código que demonstrem como a resposta atende ao que foi perguntado?" (só um exemplo, com certeza a redação pode ser melhorada; incluí o link - escapado - pra ficar fácil copiar e colar)

Comment: @mgibsonbr É, adaptado, porque foi escrito correndo e podia ser melhor :)

Comment: @bigown Pois é, estou sugerindo deixar um comentário "*boilerplate*" pronto justamente pra isso... (embora também não estou 100% satisfeito com o meu) A propósito, será que essa pergunta é a melhor pra indicar pros novos usuários, ou devemos colocar uma mais "didática"? (essa aqui está mais como um debate mesmo, sem **explicação do porquê** respostas só com links não são muito boas)

Comment: Deveriam ser convertidas em Comentário por um moderador.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8003/o-que-fazer-com-publica%c3%a7%c3%b5es-que-dependem-de-algo-que-n%c3%a3o-existe-mais?cb=1

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Respostas com links são ótimas. Não entenda errado. O problema aparece quando as respostas têm **apenas** links.

E não estamos falando só do link e mais nada. Ter algum texto que pouco ou nada acrescenta à resposta também é ruim.

Precisamos de **[respostas reais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/507/perguntas-verdadeiras-tem-respostas), relevantes e duradoras**. Note que os sites da rede Stack Exchange tem uma preocupação muito forte com a qualidade das respostas ou mesmo das perguntas. O conteúdo encontrado nestes dois tipos de postagens são fundamentais para o site. Eles não podem ser confundidos com postagens típicas de fóruns e listas de discussão, onde se estabelece uma conversa sobre o assunto e o principal objetivo é achar *qualquer* solução para o autor do post original do tópico aberto.

Nosso site não tem tópicos abertos. Tem perguntas feitas. É importantíssimo entender essa diferença.

E **perguntas exigem respostas**. Não apenas uma solução para o autor. Precisa de conteúdo relevante, que contenha, texto, código, imagem e outros recursos que informem o que o autor está pedindo. Também deve **servir para qualquer outra pessoa que no futuro chegue na pergunta**.

Links são **ótimos como complemento** para informação mais detalhada ou adicional ao que foi perguntado, são praticamente obrigatórios para dar crédito a quem escreveu o texto base que você usou para formular sua resposta ou que você citou. Mas links sozinhos são péssimos porque eles podem não existir mais no futuro e **a resposta precisa continuar respondendo a pergunta no futuro**. Se a "resposta" só tem o link e ele deixa de existir ou não tem mais a mesma informação, a resposta passa estar errada.

Quer outro problema? O SOpt pode não estar bloqueado na empresa que o usuário trabalha, mas o site do link pode estar bloqueado.

Links sozinhos não ajudam outros desenvolvedores ou curiosos que têm um problema semelhante. Eles vão procurar no Google e encontrar apenas as respostas que tenham conteúdo relevante para ser indexado. Um link não tem conteúdo que ajudam os buscadores.

Quer ganhar reputação? **Ajude sua resposta ser achada**, coloque conteúdo que faça ela ser localizada no Google ou outro buscador. A pessoa acha sua reposta, gosta do conteúdo que está ali e vota nela. Se ele simplesmente for direcionado para outro lugar, nem dá tempo de votar na sua resposta.

Outro problema comum é o link não ter exatamente o que o autor perguntou. Pode até ter também, mas não de forma objetiva, como só você pode dar, já que está lendo a pergunta dele.

Faça **pelo menos um resumo do que tem no link**. Forneça algum contexto para o link. Diga porque o link é útil, reforce alguma parte, **cite**, através do [uso justo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use), o que é mais relevante. Pequenas diferenças podem fazer toda diferença.

Não fique frustrado se receber votos negativos ou sua resposta seja transformada em comentário se ela conter apenas link.

Answer (score 43):

Eu não simpatizo nem um pouco com esse tipo de resposta, embora entenda que elas possam ajudar muita gente. Porém considero que o ponto principal do site não seja simplesmente ajudar as pessoas, mesmo isso sendo em boa parte o que fazemos. O ponto principal para mim é criar um repositório de conteúdo de qualidade.

Nesse sentido, os links são um ponto fraco. Devemos trabalhar para concentrar conteúdo de qualidade **aqui mesmo**, e não simplesmente resolver o problema de quem está perguntando. Nada garante que no futuro estes links continuarão funcionando, então é importante fazer um resumo do que está no link (ou até cópia, com a devida citação, se não for um conteúdo muito longo). Então, ao encontrar uma resposta que só contém link, considere complementar o conteúdo, ou pedir ao autor que faça isso, como [sugerido pelo Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/59/74).

Se tudo que se tem para postar é um link, seria melhor que fosse um comentário, não uma resposta. Nesse caso, se considerar que o link realmente acrescenta algo de útil, sinalize com o motivo "outro" e peça a um moderador que converta para comentário (só moderadores podem fazer isso). Cuidado: se você sinalizar como "não é uma resposta", a resposta vai para a fila de publicações de baixa qualidade, e tem altas chances de acabar simplesmente sendo excluída por outros usuários, e nem ser vista pelos moderadores.

Por fim: às vezes o problema é da pergunta, que está de fato solicitando uma lista de tutoriais ou ferramentas. Perguntas desse tipo geram muitas respostas só com link, e sou a favor de fechá-las.

Comment: Inclusive porque não ajuda tanto assim. O grosso do nosso tráfego deve vir do Google (ok, qualquer buscador) e respostas mancas não ajudam nisso. O texto da resposta vai ajudar muito o usuário que pode nem conhecer o SOpt chegar ao que ele precisa.

Comment: Alguns links podem, na maioria das vezes, levar para sites em outra língua o que foge do escopo do SOpt.
Talvez sugerir como resposta, em vez de link, que procure por "palavra chave" para se aprofundar no assunto ou mais referências.

Comment: concordo. Muito boas as respostas completas que encontrei no SOEN. As melhores são sempre concisas, limpas, objetivas. Ainda que a resposta seja complexa, vejo o SO como uma oportunidade de exercitar conhecimento, e escrever, refletir e ponderar sobre uma resposta é válido pra quem responde e pra quem tem sua pergunta respondida. Responder com link quem faz é o google.

Comment: "Nada garante que no futuro estes links continuarão funcionando." A meu ver, esta é a parte mais importante. É comum links **morrerem** e, nesse caso, a resposta torna-se inútil se não tiver mais nada.

Answer (score 26):

Respostas com nada além de um link são, francamente, péssimas. Exigem mais trabalho de todo mundo que acompanha o tópico, o link pode morrer e, no final das contas, **uma referência não é um resposta**.

O melhor a se fazer é resumir (não só copiar) o conteúdo do link, pegando a parte relevante à pergunta e colocando dentro do seu post. Dessa forma, todo mundo que chegar naquela pergunta vai saber do que o link se trata, e como ele pode ajudar, sem precisar clicar nele. E, caso queira mais detalhes, só ir lá ler do que se trata.

No exemplo citado, entretanto, o link faz sentido... A resposta podia ser mais completa (exemplo de código, por exemplo) mas não é de todo ruim, já que era a recomendação de uma ferramenta que solucionaria o problema...

Comment: Verdade, escolhi um exemplo ruim (que considero exemplo de outro problema, perguntas que pedem recomendações).

Answer (score 13):

Não acho que devam ser aceitas respostas com somente links, no entanto **links de referência são muito úteis**, inclusive para dar mais credibilidade e dar um caminho a se aprofundar no tema, que nem sempre é o objetivo das respostas.

**Nem todos os links vão aparecer nos buscadores**, muitos estão no que alguns chamam da "deep-web" (não sou a favor do termo), seja por intenção, pelo buscador considerar de baixa relevância, dentre outros motivos. Portanto muitas vezes um link que é dado como referência aqui não é encontrado facilmente, ou mesmo não encontrado, nos buscadores.

**Links quebrados sempre serão um problema**, porem citações trazem parte do conteúdo que importa ao contexto a resposta, não deixando-a sem conteúdo.

**Ferramentas como o** *web archive* podem agir de forma parecida com o buscador, não encontrando e portando não armazenando o conteúdo do link informado, e ainda, a própria ferramenta pode se tornar um link quebrado caso deixe de existir. Portanto sou contra qualquer ideia de somente aceitar links a uma ferramenta específica.

---

Resumindo, links de referência dão credibilidade e fonte a resposta nos casos necessários. Nas citações, o conteúdo relevante está copiado com a devida permissão, sendo o link uma ajuda para aprofundamento e crédito. Totalmente diferente de respostas "link-only"

Comment: E, se não me engano, o site coloca nofollow nos links que estão dentro de perguntas e respostas.

Answer (score 6):

Só links complicam a vida. O melhor é copiar o conteúdo principal, que se aplica a resposta, e referenciar o original com link.

Comment: O problema é quando o conteúdo do link é gigante (por exemplo, um tutorial). Aí seria preciso resumir. Outro caso (que é o do exemplo linkado na pergunta) são links de ferramentas recomendadas. Aí a questão é sabermos se queremos ou não aceitar perguntas sobre recomendação de ferramentas... Se não quisermos, podemos fechar/excluir a pergunta, e o problema da resposta se resolve sozinho.

Comment: Sim, no caso do tutorial você resume. No caso das ferramentas, apenas colocando o nome delas do lado dos links já ajuda bastante. Na informática o mundo anda depressa, o que é novidade hoje, amanhã é coisa de museu. No máximo poderíamos exigir que as pessoas só colocassem links do [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/), mas não seria prático. ;)

Comment: Acho que vamos precisar abrir uma discussão sobre querermos ou não perguntas de recomendação de ferramenta. Eu acho que deveríamos fechar essas perguntas, mas ainda é cedo para definir isso.

Comment: Discordo completamente dos links de recomendação. Até podemos aceitar esse tipo de questão, mas ela deveria ser muito bem feita, com requisitos bem definidos, contextualizados e as respostas que é o objeto principal aqui, devem ser bem justificadas. Recomendação com link mais qualquer texto irrelevante é motivo para deleção na hora.

Comment: Sou contra copiar o conteúdo de outro site e colocar aqui só porque não querem colocar links. Links são um fundamento da web e não podemos ficar copiando conteúdo alheio sem permissão. Normalmente eu resumo e insiro um link para a fonte.

Answer (score 4):

Um problema grave a longo prazo gerado por respostas desse tipo, é que não há garantias de por quanto tempo aquele link vai continuar ativo na mesma url.
No stackoverflow já me deparei diversas vezes com soluções que estavam "disponíveis" em links quebrados.

Não vejo nenhum problema em colocar um link de referencia, principalmente se a referencia for outra pergunta do site. Mas o cerne da solução deveria ser colocado na resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Respostas que tem somente links são respostas ruins.

Além dos problemas já citados nas outras respostas, um grande problema dos links é o *link rot*: o link que funciona hoje tem grande chance de não funcionar daqui a 1 ano.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não gosto nem um pouco desse tipo de resposta, mas já me beneficiei de *link-only*.

Acho que se esse tipo de resposta pode ficar por ali mesmo, **sem receber nenhum voto**, está bom...

Creio que aqui na área de postar uma resposta poderia haver uma mensagem com um link para um `FAQ` de como postar uma boa resposta. E neste tópico incluir uma boa explicação de porque respostas com apenas um link não são boas e etc...

[image: Mensagem]

Answer (score 1):

Tópico bastante antigo esse, não havia lido ele de antemão por não achar necessário, haja vista eu já conhecer a metodologia de trabalho e funcionamento da Stack Exchange.

Mas já que me "empurraram" para cá, gostaria de deixar meus dois *cents* aqui tanto para àqueles que vierem a comentar ou mesmo a editar um *stack* ou resposta que contenha apenas um pouco texto apenas para contextualizar um link auto-explicativo, que seja feita uma ponderação antes.

Ponderação no sentido de analisar o *stack* como um todo primeiro antes de caracterizar mentalmente que uma resposta visivelmente simplória é realmente nociva ao modelo de um modo geral ou apenas complementar, a qual muitas vezes não importa se carece de elaboração ou não.

Comment: Ser muito curta e conter link por si só não quer dizer que a resposta deva ser excluída. Muitas vezes deve ser convertida em comentário (o que ficou mais difícil depois de uma mudança recente no sistema). Outras vezes simplesmente responde à pergunta. Mas com muita frequência é indício de uma resposta que precisa ser editada, convertida para comentário ou excluída.

Comment: Sim, sim, o caso em particular foi quanto à uma dúvida em JavaScript que não é exatamente do meu domínio E no *stack* em questão já haviam várias respostas muito bem elaboradas, inclusive com pagamento de recompensa para outra pessoa que não o autor da resposta aceita. Colocar um comentário, descontextualizaria a sugestão, mas também não justificava dissertar sobre o assunto.