# Perguntas verdadeiras têm respostas

Tags: debate, perguntas

Ainda estamos tentando descobrir todos os casos em que devemos fechar uma pergunta. A maioria dos critérios serão os mesmos do Stack Overflow, outros sofrerão algumas adaptações.

Mas com tantos critérios para analisar, fica difícil chegar a uma decisão.

Estou lendo postagens antigas no [Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/) e no [meta principal da rede](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) e achei um artigo bem interessante: [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

Ele resume bem como devemos decidir sobre o fechamento de perguntas por critérios de subjetividade e amplitude.

Esqueça as ideias que foram enraizadas nos outros sites da rede, muitas delas que até foram tratadas oficialmente no blog ou no metão como atitudes erradas. Muitas vezes tentamos ser tão corretos que exageramos. Se uma pergunta não traz problemas para a saúde da comunidade, porque ela deveria ser fechada? Claro que precisa haver um critério para definir o que faz mal à saúde do site.

Precisamos tentar entender melhor os motivos para fechar uma pergunta, o que deve ser evitado sempre que possível.

Não importa tanto como a pergunta foi feita, importa se é possível obter respostas corretas e úteis para esse site. Se a pergunta está resolvendo um problema, mesmo que ela não esteja em sua forma ideal, vamos tentar, em colaboração com o autor, administrá-la para que possa obter respostas. Não necessariamente uma única resposta correta, mas que se possa estabelecer que uma delas é correta e aceitável pelo autor.

Apesar de haver cinco motivos determinados para fechar uma pergunta e várias diretrizes e critérios para adotar na análise, só um aspecto realmente importa:

**Perguntas de verdade têm *respostas*, não *itens*, não *ideias* e não *opiniões*.**

Comment: Hm, nenhuma resposta aqui por enquanto. Será que esta é uma pergunta verdadeira? :)

Comment: Se alguém discordar ou tiver um complemento é só responder.

Comment: @bfavaretto Essa pergunta deveria ter mais votos. Será que o pessoal não entendeu a sua piada e levou a sério?

Comment: Será? Quer que eu apague?

Comment: Não, paciência. Piada é bom.

Answer (score 10):

> #### Tradução do Artigo completo de Jeff Atwood, [*Real questions have answers*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

*[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective)* foi um bom começo para definirmos o que seria uma **pergunta subjetiva *construtiva***, e essa definição tem funcionado bem até agora:

> 1. Grandes questões subjetivas inspiram respostas que explicam o "porquê" e o "como".
> 2. Grandes questões subjetivas tendem a ter respostas longas e não curtas.
> 3. Grandes questões subjetivas têm um tom construtivo, justo e imparcial.
> 4. Grandes questões subjetivas convidam a partilha de experiências e não de opiniões.
> 5. Grandes questões subjetivas insistem que opiniões devem ser apoiadas por fatos e referências.
> 6. Grandes questões subjetivas são mais do que diversão social boba.

No entanto, as seis diretrizes acima dependem em parte das pergunta, e em parte das respostas. São um bom começo para determinar em linhas gerais o que é uma pergunta subjetiva – mas não consegui explicar totalmente o que define uma pergunta subjetiva ruim.

Até que eu vi a [resposta épica do Aarobot no MSE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/75168/should-polls-be-maintained-as-community-wiki-questions-or-should-they-be-closed/75179#75179) sobre perguntas do tipo enquete:

> **Todas as perguntas subjetivas devem ser fechadas?** É aí que a coisa complica. Veja só, o termo "enquete" é subjetivo por si só, e o próprio fato de uma pergunta ser ou não uma enquete muitas vezes dá margem a discussões.
>
> Para mim, e acho que para muitos outros também, o único momento em que se tem certeza de estar olhando para uma pergunta de enquete é quando aparecem aquelas respostas de uma só linha. Mas podemos apenas fechar essas perguntas. É sempre culpa de quem pergunta se as respostas são ruins? Eles merecem ser culpados pelo fato de que pessoas com nada útil a dizer quererem participar de qualquer meneira, com seus "tweets" estilo reddit nas respostas?
>
> Às vezes as questões são bem ruins mesmo. Quando alguém pergunta *[Which programming language do you really hate?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2846/3249)*, e nem se importa em elaborar melhor a pergunta, isso é pedir por respostas ruins. É difícil eu me irritar com esses usuários por suas respostas (tá bom, talvez eu me irrite só um pouco) porque a pergunta em si era tão aberta que qualquer resposta poderia ter tecnicamente considerada "correta".
>
> Então, de novo, algumas perguntas formuladas como enquetes óbvias acabam até recebendo respostas razoáveis e bem-escritas. Veja por exemplo *[Best practices that you disagree with](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/14856/3249)*. No Seasoned Advice (Cooking.SE), posso mostrar diversos exemplos de [perguntas fracas](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9562/41) ou mesmo [perguntas-piada](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9533/41) que, dada uma resposta rápida e completa, acabaram não virando bá-blá-blá. Por outro lado, já vi perguntas que claramente não eram enquetes e mesmo assim receberam várias respostas de baixa qualidade; por exemplo, uma das mais antigas do Stack Overflow: *[Practical non-image based CAPTCHA approaches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8472/38360)*.
>
> Recentemente, tenho usado as [diretrizes do Metafilter](http://faq.metafilter.com/tags/chatfilter) como referência.

Sim, sim, é um texto longo, quase TL;DR, mas é excelente. [Leia](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/75168/should-polls-be-maintained-as-community-wiki-questions-or-should-they-be-closed/75179#75179). Talvez você já conheça do Aarobot pela sua [descoberta anterior sobre as meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Não surpreende que o [Metafilter](http://www.metafilter.com/), que tem trabalhado com Perguntas e Respostas de qualidade desde 2004, fez essas descobertas anos atrás. Ele são uma grande influência, tanto quanto a Wikipedia. Por isso recebemos o Josh Millard, admin do Metafilter, [num dos primeiros podcasts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/podcast-22/).

Pena que não descobri antes esse link que o Aarobot citou. A partir de agora, todos os sites da rede passam a incluir **orientações específicas sobre o que é uma pergunta subjetiva ruim**.

> Você deve fazer apenas perguntas práticas, que admitam respostas com base em problemas reais que tiver. Perguntas extensas e abertas diminuem a utilidade de nosso site e retiram outras perguntas da página inicial.
>
> (...)
>
> Para evitar que sua pergunta seja sinalizada e possivelmente removida, evite fazer perguntas subjetivas onde …
>
> - toda resposta seja igualmente válida: “Qual é seu __ favorito?”
> - sua resposta seja fornecida junto com a pergunta e você espera mais respostas: “Eu uso __ para __, o que você usa?”
> - não haja um problema real para resolver: “Tenho curiosidade de saber se outras pessoas se sentem como eu.”
> - você faça uma pergunta hipotética e aberta: “E se acontecer __?”
> - sua pergunta seja apenas uma reclamação disfarçada: “__ é péssimo, concordam comigo?”
>
> Se a sua motivação para fazer a pergunta for “eu gostaria de participar de uma discussão sobre __”, você não deve fazer uma pergunta aqui. No entanto, se a sua motivação for “eu gostaria que outros me expliquem __”, provavelmente está no lugar certo.

Tudo isso foi baseado na postagem do FAQ do Metalfilter *[My Ask Metafilter question was removed as chatfilter. What does that mean?](http://faq.metafilter.com/tags/chatfilter)*, conforme permissão deles e com a devida citação.

Eu sei que são muitas regras e diretrizes, muito o que pensar. Mas é mais simples do que parece. Como disse o Aarobot em seu post: **perguntas verdadeiras têm respostas, não itens, não ideias, não opiniões.**