# Devo sinalizar todas as perguntas que se mostrarem "concursos de popularidade"?

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise, moderação, sinalização

Praticamente uma vez por dia percebo por aqui uma pergunta como essas:

- Qual é a melhor linguagem para desenvolver meu projeto?
- Qual é o melhor banco de dados?
- Qual é o melhor sistema de controle de fontes?
- PHP ou JQuery, como prosseguir?

E assim segue. Quando me deparo com esse tipo de pergunta, meu instinto é sinalizar no mesmo instante, pois estas **sempre** se tornam concurso de popularidade.

O problema é que alguns usuários se sentem ofendidos pelos comentários ou até pela sinalização em si.

Outra questão é que por via de regra, a melhor linguagem, o melhor método, o melhor banco de dados é aquele que dominamos. Cada um vai, salvo raras exceções, defender o seu lado e raramente algo construtivo sai dali. Ao final do dia, quem perguntou vai ler as respostas e escolher a melhor formatada, mais clara e oriunda do usuário mais *"famoso"*.

Enfim, segue minha pergunta:
**Devo seguir sinalizando esse tipo de pergunta ou deixar pra ver que fim leva?**

Gostaria de levantar este fórum para saber a opinião dos demais membros do SOP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Por enquanto, pode continuar sinalizando. Em breve - quando você chegar aos 500 de reputação - você também poderá **votar pra fechar**. A razão de fechamento é clara e direta: "Principalmente baseado em opiniões".

Quanto aos usuários se sentirem ofendidos, paciência! Algumas coisas é a comunidade que decide, outras é a própria StackExchange, e perguntas excessivamente subjetivas e/ou que busquem somente opiniões e [gerem discussões, não respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/507/215), **não são adequadas para o formato do site**. Se um usuário novo não consegue entender isso - mesmo após a comunidade ser paciente (e, de preferência, bem educada - não faz sentido antagonizar os novatos) e fazer o possível para orientá-los, então não há o que fazer... É preciso ser firme, do contrário a qualidade do site se deteriora.

P.S. Todo mundo é bem vindo a expressar sua opinião no meta, as regras desse site não vêm [todas] "de cima", então se alguém questionar sua sinalização e/ou comentário, convide-o a expor seu caso aqui.

Comment: Achei a resposta interessante porque tem havido uma onde não vamos ferir os sentimentos das pessoas que estão fazendo algo errado na comunidade. Embora eu ache que é bom evitar atritos, isso não deve acontecer em detrimento da filosofia do site.