# Uma lista assim seria bem aceita no SOpt?

Tags: debate

[Lista no Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207710/what-are-examples-of-comments-that-tell-you-why-instead-of-how-or-what) sobre comentários.

Esta é uma lista dentro do nosso escopo (eu acho), está claro o que está sendo perguntado, não **me** parece pedir opiniões e sim casos concretos e não é muito amplo. Pode até produzir muitas respostas, mas isso por si só não é um problema. Se fosse, haveria limitação na quantidade de respostas permitidas. Hoje nem há limita para a pergunta virar Community Wiki automaticamente.

Ela é de todo boa? Não. É uma lista de itens que não possui uma resposta absolutamente certa. Mas isso sozinho não é o fim do mundo. É uma lista que pelo menos não correr o risco de ficar desatualizada. Dá para ganhar reputação fácil com isso, mas em geral a reputação só virá de respostas realmente úteis. E você pode avaliar as respostas pelo seu valor em si. É diferente de livros, por exemplo, em que você não sabe se vota na resposta ou no livro citado. neste caso a resposta tem valor por si própria.

O que acham? Vamos ser rígidos ou vamos avaliar a pergunta como um todo, entender a utilidade dela?

Tem algo realmente ruim que eu não vi nela? A comunidade do Programmers achou que é opinião. Mas vejo tanta coisa aberta lá que é opinião também. Essa pode até ser uma opinião, admito isso, mas a resposta pode trazer algo útil baseado em experiência.

Ou há problema por ser lista e ponto?

Se isso é opinião, [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15488/como-saber-a-medida-certa-de-comentarios/15566#15566) também é?

Comment: Meu voto é por manter aberta! Conteúdo útil e de qualidade.

Comment: `"não me parece pedir opiniões e sim casos concretos e não é muito amplo"` Concordo. Me parece ser algo bem aceitável aqui. BTW deixei alguns votos positivos na pergunta mencionada no final.

Comment: Bem-aceita eu acho que pode ser sim. Mas quais seriam as consequências de se manter uma pergunta assim no site? Que outros tipos de pergunta precisariam ser mantidas abertas para sermos coerentes com essa decisão? Isso precisa ser discutido. Outra coisa é que *tenho a impressão* de que a votação nesse tipo de lista tende a acabar distorcida (por exemplo, um comentário bem-humorado e divertido ganharia mais votos que um que explique melhor o porquê do código que segue).

Comment: @bfavaretto boa observação. Ainda estou esperando alguém se arriscar mais em uma resposta :) Mas tem tempo para isso.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esse é o caso principal das [perguntas concurso de popularidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121/devo-sinalizar-todas-as-perguntas-que-se-mostrarem-concursos-de-popularidade).

Salvo raras exceções, teremos dez respostas quase iguais, adicionando tags H1, listas e piadinhas para tentar pescar mais votos positivos e consequentemente reputação fácil.

> Outra questão é que por via de regra, a melhor linguagem, o melhor método, o melhor banco de dados é aquele que dominamos. Cada um vai, salvo raras exceções, defender o seu lado e raramente algo construtivo sai dali. Ao final do dia, quem perguntou vai ler as respostas e escolher a melhor formatada, mais clara e oriunda do usuário mais "famoso".

Isso sem contar no precedente que este tipo de questão abre. Dez perguntas boas depois do inicio empolgante desse tipo de questão e começaremos a ver usuários querendo abrir votação para decidir qual o tipo de documentação adequada, qual é a melhor linguagem de programação ou modelo de teclado para programar melhor.

Claro que penso que estas questões seriam muito bem aceitas pela comunidade, afinal, dar pitaco é o gosto secreto de uma boa parcela de todo grupo, mas acredito que nesse universo *"borderline opinion based"* sempre veremos grandes egos se inflando e produzindo textos imensos, **às vezes** prolixos e que **em alguns casos** pouco adicionam à base de conhecimento.

Dessa forma defendo que os malefícios ultrapassam e por muito os benefícios.

*P.S.: Sobre a resposta postada ao final da sua pergunta, a sua é de longe a mais completa e a mais "humilde"(acho que humilde não cabe, está mais pra estritamente técnica), adiciona muito ao site, mas ainda assim, tomando como base a resposta mais votada e a pergunta em si, penso que a pergunta toda não devia estar em um site como o SOP. Talvez em um forum ou blog, mas não aqui.*

Comment: Se entendi certo, que pena que você não gosta dos meus longos e prolixos textos :P Eu acho que o SOpt poderia ser uma ferramenta para mudar a postura e o entendimento que os programadores têm. Sei que não vou resolver o problema do mundo, mas acho que posso fazer a minha parte. Realmente não gosto (mas respeito) as respostas do tipo peixe (fritinho, com limão). Acho bom ter diversidade. Mas gosto de ter aqui algo um pouco diferente do que o SO sempre foi. Discordo da 1a. parte sobre a pergunta específica. Eu vejo algo útil e praticamente objetivo. Mas consigo ver o mesmo que você na 2a. parte.

Comment: Eu tendo a concordar que perguntas ruins atraem mais perguntas ruins. Mas não sei se essa é o caso. Não sei se é tão difícil diferenciar ela das piadinhas. Não sei se não dá para aceitar um pouco de trabalho para fechar as que passam desse limite, para dar espaço para algo que seja útil. Não sei, por isso estou querendo opiniões.

Comment: Ao contrario, @bigown, *elogiei* sua resposta e informei que ela sozinha seria muito bem vinda no site, ao contrário da mais votada que é extremamente longa, conta a história da vida e as vitórias do criador, porém quando chega ao assunto simplesmente não entrega o que prometeu.

Comment: "Porque estava eu pescando com o orientador do meu phd em harvard, o dia estava frio, eu sentia fome, porém minha enorme tenacidade não me deixou desistir" Tá, mas e a norma dos comentários?

Comment: @bigown O problema de separar o joio do trigo como diz seu segundo comentário é a rejeição da comunidade. Se o infeliz que leu deu uma risadinha, ele vai dar upvote e isso vai virar isca pra oportunista. Aí você corta as asas do autor e ele vem no meta reclamar da reputação que "perdeu" (e não devia ter ganho)

Comment: @bigown o P.S. da minha resposta diz tudo sobre o que vejo, por via de regra nas suas respostas e nas do mgibsonbr. Técnica, explicação e objetividade sem massagear o monstrinho do ego.

Comment: Eu acho que a minha faz algo bem semelhante. Eu gosto de contar minhas experiências quando acho que ela dá um tom mais menos opinativo, ser um subjetivo bom. As minhas respostas são longas mesmo, eu sei que cometo o erro da prolixia. Mas de fato eu respondi porque achei que as outras entregavam bem pouco do que a pergunta pedia. Acho engraçado que talvez eu acho mais coisas negativas nas minhas respostas que você :). Mas entendi o que você escreveu nisto e na questão de abrir a possibilidade para o voto no popular. E saiba que eu odeio isso em qualquer lugar.

Comment: @bigown contar experiência <> se gabar. A diferença fica clara. Quanto à "prolixia", estando dentro do subjetivo bom, está valendo, tanto que acaba até saindo um pouco do significado da palavra. Um texto longo com muita informação nunca é enfadonho, as adições acabam sendo a cola que une tantos fatos juntos.