# Pergunta de como fazer ou sugestão, pode?

Tags: debate, como-perguntar

Estou precisando implementar uma rotina Web, que vai usar achar e cadastro de um para muitos. Existe várias formas de fazer, mas não sei qual é a mais correta ou a melhor em codificação.

A pergunta é: Posso fazer uma pergunta falando das formas que deseja fazer e pedir opinião qual delas é a mais "correta".

Ou é errado fazer isto?

Answer (score 11):

Antes de mais nada, leia [a respeito de quais tópicos posso fazer perguntas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) e saiba  [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Este tipo de problema que você está enfrentando é algo muito comum a todos os desenvolvedores, porém a resposta correta varia muito de caso para caso.

Não é absolutamente errado fazer esse tipo de pergunta, desde que a pergunta tenha uma reposta objetiva.

Particularmente, acredito que uma pergunta bem formulada, que defina bem o assunto, os requisitos desejados e demonstre um esforço de pesquisa tenha boa aceitação dos usuários.

**Minha sugestão é: faça a pergunta. Mas...**

- **Contextualize-a**: qual linguagem, plataforma, *framework* está sendo usado? Qual é o objetivo que você quer alcançar?
- **Limite o escopo**: defina restrições, isto é, o que você espera que as respostas abordem. É a questão da modelagem? É como passar do modelo para o código?
- **Demonstre esforço**: mostre até que ponto você chegou, coloque exemplos de código e do modelo.
- **Esteja aberto à crítica**: se a pergunta não estiver boa, ela provavelmente será fechada. Os usuários provavelmente deixarão comentários. Aproveite o *feedback* que eles vão dar, usando-o para melhorar a pergunta.
- **Busque uma resposta objetiva**: **não peça a opinião** dos usuários. Elabore a pergunta pensando em obter uma resposta madura e bem embasada.

Answer (score 8):

Eu sugiro a leitura do ["Gorilla vs. Shark"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/488/215). Em resumo, você pode sim fazer esse tipo de pergunta desde que tome os devidos cuidados:

- Esclareça bem qual é o **contexto**: duas (ou mais) técnicas distintas para realizar o mesmo objetivo podem ter cada uma seus prós e contras, de modo que seria incorreto afirmar que "uma é melhor que a outra". Se você especificar bem qual é a sua situação, fica mais fácil de se analisar cada uma delas à luz do seu cenário particular (i.e. talvez a A e a B não se adequem ao seu caso pelos motivos X e Y, a C esteja OK mas a D seja ainda melhor pelas razões Z e W).
- Foque [no seu problema, e não na sua tentativa de solução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/215): listar as formas que você conhece para resolver não atrapalha, mas deixe a pergunta aberta de modo que respostas distintas sejam possíveis. Quem sabe existe uma maneira diferente de resolver seu problema, que você não pensou, e que seja ainda melhor que as alternativas consideradas. Se você formular a pergunta no modo X vs. Y ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2044/215), [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3274/215)) as respostas virão naturalmente focadas nesses modos específicos e em nenhum outro (o que em muitos casos pode ser exatamente o que você quer, mas aqui seu objetivo é resolver um problema bem específico).
- Estabeleça parâmetros para escolher uma resposta como "certa": quando se pede para analisar uma tecnologia, técnica ou ferramenta, muitas vezes pessoas diferentes farão isso sob um ponto de vista diferente, produzindo ótimas respostas onde uma não é superior a outra (e sim complementares). Isso não é necessariamente ruim, mas o ideal [para o formato do site] é que você possa escolher uma delas como ["a resposta certa"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/507/215). Assim, deixe bem claro o que está procurando saber, de modo que mesmo que os respondentes se desviem um pouco, ainda assim seja possível dizer pelo menos "a resposta X cobriu todos os pontos perguntados" (não que seja necessariamente a única a fazê-lo).

Ou seja, desde que escrita de forma que não fique muito ampla (uma boa resposta daria um livro), excessivamente restrita (só serve pra você e pra ninguém mais), ou somente baseada em opiniões (toda resposta é válida), não vejo problema em se fazer uma pergunta desse tipo.

P.S. E se ainda assim sua pergunta não for bem recebida, leia com atenção aos comentários e tente seguir suas sugestões de melhora - muitas vezes dá pra "salvar" uma pergunta ainda que num primeiro momento ela venha a ser fechada por diversos motivos.