# Quais critérios devemos levar em consideração na escolha de uma Bibliografia?

Tags: debate, respostas, hyperlinks

O Stack Overflow em Português é uma ótima ferramenta de estudos, e a qualidade das perguntas e respostas refletem diretamente no dia a dia de nós desenvolvedores. Segundo @Maniero, surge a necessidade de **[respostas reais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/507/perguntas-verdadeiras-t%c3%aam-respostas), relevantes e duradoras**, nesta sequência, foi discutido sobre [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links).

Neste sentido, reforça-se que um *link*, e uma **citação** deve vir para complementar uma resposta de qualidade, apesar disso, linguagens são atualizadas, `métodos` são depreciados e *links* podem ser expirados. Podemos encontrar em diferentes sites, respostas e definições para um mesmo conteúdo.

Nessa perspectiva, no desenvolvimento de uma resposta quais critérios devemos levar em consideração na escolha de uma Bibliografia?

Comment: Não entendi bem a dúvida, seria algo como "que tipo de fonte deve ser usada ou não?", se sim, qualquer uma que seja útil (se não agrega nada a resposta não tem o porque adicionar) e confiável (se não é possível afirmar que seu conteúdo está correto, ela só irá degradar a resposta)

Comment: Não é mandatório mas se quer apresentar boa e confiável informação em seus links, no caso linguagens de programação de preferência a documentação oficial do fabricante ou consorcio/organização mantenedora do padrão da linguagem. Em caso de algoritmo mais sofisticado dê preferência a tese do(s) criado(res), em caso de algoritmo domínio publico e autor desconhecido pode usar um catalogo de algoritmo online. Em caso de norma técnica use a própria documentação emitida pelo órgão ou comitê normatizador. Se nenhuma dessas fontes estiver disponível vai de wikpedia.

Comment: Como já dito, sobre programação sempre cito a documentação oficial (ou uma documentação reconhecida, como MDN para JS). Sobre *links podem ser expirados*, traga a parte relevante para a resposta e isso não será um problema grave.

Comment: "*linguagens são atualizadas, métodos são depreciados*" - Partindo da ideia principal de que uma resposta deve ter todo o conteúdo relevante, sem depender de links externos (as partes essenciais ao entendimento e completude da resposta devem ficar no SOpt), e links servem apenas como complemento, então isso não vai afetar somente os links, mas sim toda a resposta. E nesse caso, ela pode muito bem ser editada e atualizada (ou alguém pode escrever outra resposta), ou então coloca-se um aviso dizendo que aquilo funciona até a versão X, etc.