# O que fazer com respostas curtas?

Tags: debate, comportamento, respostas

Respostas curtas não costumam ser boas, muitas vezes podem ser consideradas de baixa qualidade.

Precisamos de diretrizes para os usuários saberem o que fazer e como os moderadores devem tratá-las também.

Temos até um caso especial que já [ficou praticamente decidido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links) que respostas que apenas contenham links não são boas. Só falta definir o que fazer com elas.

Comment: Eu, quando tenho uma resposta curta (que costuma ser incompleta), costumo postá-la como um comentário. A menos que ela seja realmente suficiente e não possa haver mais explicações que não sejam encheção de linguiça.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Em geral, o melhor a fazer quando se encontra uma resposta curta, é prover uma melhor. Todo mundo se beneficia disso.

Se realmente ela for ruim, o usuário pode **sinalizar** para um moderador tomar uma providência. Mas o usuário precisa ter certeza que a resposta é ruim. Embora seja altamente provável que um resposta muito curta seja ruim, nem sempre isso é verdade. Se houver abuso na sinalização de respostas ruins, a solução vira problema.

Mesmo no caso de respostas *link-only* que a probabilidade de ser ruim é muito maior, quase absoluta, devemos tomar cuidado em sinalizar algo que não está causando mal. Leia mais no link postado na pergunta acima.

**Votar contra** é livre para qualquer um. Eu raramente voto contra esse tipo de resposta, mas não vejo mal em fazer.

**Editar para torná-la útil não é uma opção**. Respostas são diferentes de perguntas. Respostas ruins não devem ser melhoradas por uma série de razões que não convêm discutir aqui. Melhorias em respostas devem se limitar a formação, gramático e estilo para dar melhor entendimento, mas nada no seu conteúdo. Se você acha que pode melhorar a resposta, faça melhor, dê você a sua resposta, mesmo que baseada na resposta curta. Se a sua for melhor, será votada, e talvez até aceita. O importante é termos respostas boas. Se alguém não conseguiu fazer isso, e você consegue, melhor para você.

Se tivesse uma forma de dividir a reputação ganha entre o autor original da pergunta e quem complementou com conteúdo relevante talvez até poderia ser uma opção. Como não é, aproveite a dica deixada pelo autor e faça a sua uma resposta relevante e ganhe a reputação. Assim ele aprende fazer melhor da próxima vez. **Nosso objetivo é mostrar para as pessoas que elas podem fazer melhor**. Dar exemplo é o melhor caminho.

Eventualmente pode-se **deixar um comentário**, especialmente para novatos orientando o que seria melhor ele fazer. Mas não vamos ficar *trollando* todo mundo que dá resposta curta.

Os moderadores devem tentar **converter a resposta em comentário**, se possível, se fizer sentido. Deve ser observado, que comentários devem ajudar de qualquer forma. Eles não aparecem em buscas e  não podem ser editados. Isso deve ser levado em consideração.

**Exclusão da resposta só em casos extremos** que realmente esteja atrapalhando. Quando a resposta não responde a pergunta de nenhuma forma. Vai contra os requisitos colocados pelo autor. E mesmo assim, se não pode ser convertido em comentário.

O que eu pude notar em pesquisa em diversos sites da rede. Respostas curtas são mais toleradas do que no SO. Talvez por serem sites menores, mais administráveis. Nós temos um caso especial, já tratado na pergunta sobre respostas *link-only*, principalmente pelo Gabe. Nós temos menos recursos bons em português. E muitas vezes achar uma resposta em português que sirva de ponte para um recurso em inglês não é de todo mal. Claro que a resposta precisa ser suficiente para ser achada pelos buscadores. Então vamos ser um pouco mais tolerante com respostas que não são ideais, sem deixar que isso prejudique o site. Não pode tudo, mas pode alguma coisa. **Tem que analisar a utilidade**.

Acho que isso vai ao encontro do que é usado em outros sites e talvez até como regra oficial da plataforma. Estou errado?

Alguém discorda de algum ponto? Tem algo que possa ajudar a responder? Deixe sua resposta também.

Comment: Uma vez acrescentei uma imagem à uma resposta para "editar e torná-la útil" no SO.EN, mas depois os mods desfizeram minhas edições. Não sabia da regra, mas ela faz sentido. Só que eu ainda fico com a impressão de que, se a pessoa edita a resposta do outro, ela está fazendo de boa fé, só para ajudar a comunidade mesmo. Mas, em resumo: se forem coisas pontuais, as edições são ok; se for algo substancial, daí é melhor uma nova resposta.

Comment: @VictorHugo Não chega ser uma regra e o critério é aplicado mais ou menos, dependendo do site e da pessoa. Nem sempre podemos ter certeza do qual é a intenção da edição da resposta. Editar respostas são complicadas, porque se não ajuda nada, não deve ser feita, se muda muito, pode estar colocando palavras na boca da pessoa e é mais fácil introduzir um problema do que se imagina. Isso você entendeu. Aproveitar uma pergunta mal feita para fazer a sua facilmente ela será duplicada. Aproveitar uma resposta mal feita para fazer a sua, ajuda a comunidade. E aí a duplicada acaba ficando a ruim :)