# Voto negativo sem justificativa é válido?

Tags: suporte, comportamento, voto-contra

Recentemente fiz uma pergunta no SO em inglês onde fui bem criterioso na descrição do problema, forneci o HTML e JavaScript, exemplifique com fiddles e mesmo assim recebi downvote.

É válido recebermos downvote sem orientação de onde erramos e como podemos fazer para melhorar? Não vejo um downvote sem justificativa acrescentar em absolutamente nada de qualitativo em um sistema que para os iniciantes pode ser um pouco cansativo e difícil de entender, muito pelo contrário, faz com que alguns possíveis bons programadores simplesmente desistam do sistema por não saberem exatamente como usá-lo, não receberem orientação devida para isso e ainda terem essa navegação dificultada através dos downvotes.

Comment: `possíveis bons programadores simplesmente desistam do sistema por não saberem exatamente como usá-lo`, se um programador amador ou profissional não consegue entender este sistema (cuja documentação foi feita com muito suor e carinho), acho melhor que mude de profissão. *Please*, Philippe, não é um ataque pessoal, só quero rebater esse argumento ;)

Comment: @brasofilo talvez eu tenha me expressado mal, mas começamos com tão pouca capacidade de interagir com o sistema que quanto mais votos negativos mais tempo ficamos com poucas ações no sistema e isso pode tornar-se nada atraente para quem está começando.

Comment: Considero que ter um problema ou dúvida técnica avaliada e possivelmemte resolvida por uma *variedade de programadores gabaritados* algo bastante atraente. Acho que não tem muita desculpa, o sistema do Stack é *muito* mais simples do que qualquer linguagem de programação. O que se pede é muito pouco em troca do que se dá.

Comment: @brasofilo volto a falar, me expressei mal, a questão não é simplicidade e sim atratividade.

Comment: Bom, nesses casos é legal se você acrescentar novos argumentos à pergunta. Na verdade, vc começa relatando sua experiência no SOEn e não no SOPt... Aqui, poucas vezes vi *downvotes* não merecidos, na verdade vejo muito *upvote* não merecido, quase que dizendo "ei, sua pergunta super pobre também é bem vinda aqui" ;)

Comment: Uma pergunta que eu também queria ter uma resposta plausível

Answer (score 41, accepted):

É válido. As regras aqui basicamente são as mesmas. Temos critérios ligeiramente diferentes e claro que um escopo de assunto permitidos bem maior que o SO. Em vários posts aqui no meta você pode saber mais sobre isso.

Se a pergunta for "é desejável?", então a resposta é não. Todo mundo que vota contra deveria comentar porque está fazendo isso, ou dar *upvote* em comentário já existente.

Nem sempre isso ocorre, deveria ocorrer mais. Em alguns casos a pessoa quer se esconder, em outros a pessoa se esquece ou tem preguiça de dizer algo.

Comentar porque está dando um voto negativo é algo **altamente desejável** para ajudar o autor melhorar o que ele postou. Mas não é obrigatório.

Comment: Ao entrar no site ontem vi que aqui podemos criar uma comunidade diferente da deles, essa questão que relatei me incomoda muito, pois impede meu "crescimento" no site, do que posso ou não fazer. Acredito que seria benéfico obrigar uma justificativa e dar a opção ao usuário de optar se identificar ou não em sua justificativa, até porque alguns não se identificam por preguiça mesmo de não querer entrar em um determinado debate.

Comment: Concordo mas isso faz parte do *engine* e hoje a chance de ser modificado é próxima do zero.

Comment: Existe alguma pergunta relacionada ao que efetivamente podemos ou temos chance de conseguir mudar em relação a eles para nos orientar no que requisitar como mudança para vocês moderadores?

Comment: Nada ainda, mas a regra básica é que o *engine* não vai mudar por causa de um site. Ou muda para todos os sites ou não muda nada. Mudanças para toda a rede devem ser feitas no [metão](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). Mas a maioria dessas coisas que você pode imaginar já foram tentadas e declinadas. O que podemos estabelecer é como nós mesmo devemos nos comportar. Coisas que podem ser recomendadas para as pessoas fazerem. Mesmo isso não poderá descaracterizar muito o padrão adotado nos outros sites. Podemos ser mais flexíveis mas não muito. Podemos mudar bastante o que é *on-topic*.

Comment: Já votaram negativo em duas postagem que eu fiz, e não explicaram exatamente nada! Aí eu fico sem saber, pensando: "onde foi que eu errei?". Se eu nem mesmo tenho a chance de melhorar o que eu postei (através do comentário crítico, vindo junto com o downvote), então sempre vou tomar votos negativos, e nunca vou melhorar em nada!

Comment: Penso que dizer que um comportamento é desejável mas não fazer nada para reforçar esse comportamento é uma incoerência da parte do Stack Overflow.

Comment: É, pelo visto 3 anos se passaram e continua acontecendo rs

Comment: Pois é, acabei de fazer uma pergunta e já negativaram em menos de 1 minuto. Dá impressão que é troll só para sacanear mesmo.

Answer (score 19):

Vejam a opinião do criador do Stack Overflow [neste tópico do Meta do original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) (é a resposta considerada "correta").

Ok, aqui não é o SO original. Mas a pergunta (e as respostas) são pertinentes a todos os sites do Stack Exchange.

Eu compartilho da opinião de um usuário chamado Shog9, que cito, verbatim:

> Downvotes, even when unjustified, are largely benign on SO: the site subtly discourages them via a small rep cost for the voter, and largely mitigates the rep damage for the author of down-voted posts by charging only 1/5 of the points granted by a corresponding upvote. If you're getting a single, stray downvote here and there, it might injure your pride, but won't actually have much of an impact on your standing among other users. (Serial down-voting is another issue, though partially addressed by existing scripts and heavily discussed in other posts here)

Tradução livre:

> Votos negativos, mesmo quando não justificados, são praticamente inofensivos no SO: o site os desencoraja sutilmente através de um pequeno custo em reputação para o votante, e não afeta tanto a reputação do autor do post uma vez que lhe toma apenas um quinto dos pontos de um voto positivo correspondente. Se você recebe um voto negativo isolado aqui ou ali, **isso pode ferir o seu ego, mas não vai afetar sua posição perante a comunidade** [ênfase minha]. (Votos negativos em série são outro problema, resolvido parcialmente por scripts e bastante discutido em outros posts por aqui).

Ou seja: se você realmente contribui para o SO, seja o original ou o lusófono, você será recompensado pela comunidade. Sentir-se incomodado por um voto negativo é consequência de um problema pessoal de auto-estima, e não de um problema técnico/conceitual do Stack Overflow.

Comment: Como não cheguei em nenhum dos sites a ter reputação suficiente para votar negativamente, não sabia que custava pontos em sua reputação fazê-lo, porém discordo e muito que votos negativos sem justificativa sejam um problema de auto-estima. Não estou aqui procurando aceitação de uma determinada comunidade para ser recompensado, eu quero sim poder usufruir de todas as funcionalidades deste sistema, conhecê-lo e desfrutá-lo por completo. Um dos moderadores daqui me indicou qual seria o possível problema na minha pergunta lá, editei e os downvotes além de sumirem ainda me renderam upvotes.

Comment: Ou seja, sem essa orientação eu teria perdido pontos, não teria ganho os pontos que ganhei e poderia continuar repetindo o erro em futuras perguntas e sendo votado negativamente, o que continuaria dificultando meu progresso no sistema.

Comment: Só custa pontos para negativar **respostas**.

Answer (score 15):

A principal função do voto negativo é ***indicar para futuros leitores*** que uma ou mais pessoas não acham que se trata de uma pergunta ou resposta útil.

Tooltip na seta de voto negativo para **Perguntas**:

> [image: esta pergunta não mostra esforço de pesquisa; não é clara ou não é útil]

Tooltip para **Respostas**:

> [image: tooltip: esta resposta não é útil]

O *ideal* seria deixar um feedback para o autor explicando o motivo, mas isso não é obrigatório (e duvido que algum dia venha ser). Ajudar o autor original é um subproduto do sistema, o produto principal é criar um repositório de Respostas úteis que beneficiem a Internet como um todo e não simplesmente o autor original da Pergunta.

E, reforçando a [resposta do Renan](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/652/voto-negativo-sem-justificativa-e-valido/674#674), o voto negativo é **no conteúdo** e não **na pessoa**.
Acho que essa confusão deixa muita gente estressada à toa e incapaz de aceitar que seu post pode ter um problema.

Comment: "Ajudar o autor original é um subproduto do sistema" Até por que tem autor que quer debater a qualquer custo a explicação, em vez de resolver o problema :)

Answer (score 10):

Começo por um trecho muito bem dito pelo @bfavaretto [em um comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200/ate-que-ponto-a-reputacao-contribui-para-a-comunidade-alem-dos-privilegios#comment2745_1203):

> Tem mais uma coisa: a reputação é o ponto central de todo o mecanismo de gamificação do site, e um grande incentivo para muita gente participar. Deixar de exibir a reputação publicamente com certeza afastaria muita gente (principalmente entre os que respondem).

Grandes reputações **de vez em quando** podem **talvez** esconder grandes egos.
Estes **supostos** grandes egos podem **talvez** se sentir feridos por um voto negativo ou um comentário contrário ao *bom senso* da maioria do grupo.
E talvez, **talvez** em uma pequena porcentagem dos casos gerar retaliações.

Além do que, o cabra pode negativar por não gostar da pergunta, não gostar do assunto, não gostar da forma que foi escrita, ter dormido de calça jeans e sapato... Enfim. Por incrível que pareça, nem sempre no voto negativo cabe um comentário.

O voto é anônimo e custa da sua própria reputação, então, para tirar a valiosa reputação desse usuário eu tenho que gastar a minha.

Finalizando, a solução para votos negativos sem sentido ao meu ver talvez seja aumentar a quantidade mínima de reputação necessária para isso e aumentar consideravelmente o custo. Assim, *"vai doer mais"* negativar e as pessoas vão pensar um pouco mais antes de apertar a setinha para baixo.

Comment: Só não concordo com o último parágrafo, acho o sistema bom como está. Talvez sua resposta tenha sido motivada por um aumento no volume de votos contra nas últimas semanas?

Comment: @bfavaretto Não. Eu sou completamente a favor dos votos contra. [Acho até que levantar a bandeira contra eles só vai aumentar o volume destes (essa questão tinha +1 quando rolou o *rant*)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13240/5769). Sugeri a mudança para agradar àqueles que se doem pelo fato de algum leitor simplesmente não gostar do que viu e negativar.

Comment: Acredito que tem alguns que fazem por puro esporte! http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13319/teclado-do-android-nao-retorna-o-keycode

Answer (score -1):

Apesar de qualquer pessoa aqui perguntada responder de prontidão que não vota negativo "por pirraça" eu duvido veementemente.

Passei boa parte da minha experiência como programador num fórum no qual reputação positiva era algo bem quisto porque era raro, a princípio, de as pessoas se darem ao trabalho de positivar como agradecimento. Sendo assim, é natural do ser humano desenvolver certo grau de competitividade.

Mas aqui, onde é mais comum essa prática, a competitividade chega algumas vezes à casos extremos onde pessoas sabotam respostas alheias para se auto-promover por saberem, lá no fundo, que se sua resposta for a mais positivada hoje, vai continuar gerando upvotes indefinidamente, no futuro.

E eu fico realmente chateado de ver pontos negativo decrescendo aquilo que conquistei aos poucos, principalmente porque pra mim, programação é um hobby e não uma profissão.

Isso porque eu nem toquei nos casos das recompensas que caso não sejam dadas pelo autor da pergunta, são dadas automaticamente para o mais positivado de um stack.

Quem hoje tem mil, 2 mil, 5 mil, 10 mil pontos conquistados, em grande parte por simples Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V de respostas de terceiros (falo com ciência, já vi vários até agora), pode se dar ao luxo de negativar sem se preocupar. mas os peixes pequenos (e nem estou falando de mim), que vêem com entusiamos seu esforço singelo sendo recompensado ao ajudar alguém ter uma queda meteórica e súbita vinda de um fanfarrão qualquer é desmotivante.

Hoje mesmo, abri minha conta e vejo 6 pontos negativos em três questões diferentes todos num período de 13h, o que indica que foi feito pela mesma pessoa sem noção.

OK, um dos casos, referente ao assunto [aqui levantado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links/1407#1407) talvez até pudesse ter uma repercussão negativa, mas eu deixei bem claro o porquê de minha contribuição se tratar apenas de um link com pouco texto.

Na minha humilde opinião, falta maturidade e consciência antes de se clicar num botãozinho só porque tem poder (e condições) pra isso

Comment: discordo de tantos pontos do seu texto que nem sei por qual começar, vou apenas falar dos seus 6 votos negativos em 13h: faça o seguinte, sinalize uma de suas publicações pedindo atenção do moderador, indique no texto que você acha que foi negativado em série, use esse termo, pois é conhecido aqui no SOPT `votos negativos em série`, o máximo que vai acontecer é voce ter sua sinalizaçao declinada caso você tenha suposto errado, caso tenha suposto certo os votos serão revertidos e o meliante receberá uma notificaçao para não fazer mais isso

Comment: Posso até fazer isso, não sei, quem sabe. Você tem todo direito de discordar, claro, mas expor minha opinião não impediu outras duas negativações. Diferente do que é feito comigo e com outros usuários (estou apenas observando), eu respeitaria sua opinião sobre os pontos todos os quais você discorda. Tenho certeza que muitos estão rindo baldes da minha posição, mas isso faço o que faço apenas para provar o que digo.

Comment: Sobre negativações aqui no meta, é apenas um meio de dizerem que discordaram da sua opinião, não afeta sua reputação no site principal. Você deu sua opinião, até o momento 3 pessoas discordaram, apenas isso, não leve para o lado pessoal. Não acho que ninguém esteja rindo de você, não vejo o por que disso, também não acham que te desrespeitaram ou te desrespeitarão.

Comment: Eu sei que os votos aqui do META não "contam" e talvez eu até esteja muito focado no "negativar, negativar, negativar" que talvez eu não esteja vendo o caso como um todo. Mas eu prezo muito honestidade e até mesmo justiça então eu só acho que quem negativa deveria ao menos ser homem o suficiente (ou mulher, quem sabe) pra dar as caras e falar "eu negativei por isso, isso e aquilo". Um dos maiores focos do META (se não o maior) é o debate. A partir do momento que fulano ou ciclano se esconde, ele mostra que não tem maturidade pra participar de uma comunidade de qualidade.

Comment: Não posso falar pelos outros, pois a sua que eu negativei eu disse claramente o motivo. Lendo outras, entenderia as razões de quem votou -1 (mas nao a ponto de eu fazer o mesmo). O engraçado é que se fosse como você diz, eu teria que "achar que é pirraça", pois tive downvotes aleatórios em coisa sem motivo. Coincidência com um post desses em seguida? Prefiro achar que sim, e que você é vítima também, em vez de sair pensando besteira. Sugestão: lembre que cada up vale 5 downs, então só uma pessoa sem noção do sistema perderia tempo com isso. Melhor tentar repensar no conteúdo da resposta.

Comment: PS: Aqui também votei -1, mas já foi explicado pelos colegas o que significa -1 no meta (não é demérito, apenas discordância).

Comment: Posso te garantir (e provar) que não fui eu quem o negativei, mesmo discordando daquele seu ponto de vista que agora já é história e não vem ao caso. Na bem da verdade, eu não negativo ninguém *et al*, nem mesmo pra ganhar a *badge* de primeiro voto contra. Se você entende as razões das outras terem sido negativadas, comente, quem sabe isso cutuca quem o fez a dar as caras. Não me importo em pontuação negativa, mas fazer apenas porque pode, além de denegrir a imagem do negativado, impede qualquer tipo de crescimento.

Comment: Se você encontrar casos de Copy/Paste sem devida atribuição, não hesite em sinalizar como plágio. Se quiser debater, avise a pessoa que está cometendo o erro, mas muitas negativar ou dar um feedback negativo pode te causar problemas, então pode ser preferível simplesmente sinalizar.

Comment: O tal "botãozinho" é uma *função* do sistema, **não é um bug**. Apertá-lo é um *direito* e um *dever*. Não concordo com sua argumentação, -1

Comment: E eu lá disse que era um bug? É esse tipo de coisa que eu acho sacanagem. Ler é bom, mas interpretar é melhor ainda. Mas pra quê fazer isso né. Xá pra lá.

Comment: Perdão pela falta de claridade... era uma referência à frase [*"It's not a bug, it's a feature"*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=It%27s%20not%20a%20bug%2C%20it%27s%20a%20feature)

Comment: Certo, desculpe pela ignorância da minha resposta, então.

Comment: Ótima resposta. Um levantamento feito a tanto tempo atrás e que ainda acontece nos dias de hoje.