# Até que ponto a reputação contribui para a comunidade além dos privilégios?

Tags: debate, reputação, privilégios

Sabemos que a **reputação** libera privilégios que permite maior interação com o site.

*Visto em "[Central de ajuda > Privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)":*

> Os privilégios controlam o que você pode fazer no Stack Overflow em Português. Obtenha mais privilégios aumentando sua reputação (pontos que você recebe de seus colegas usuários por publicar perguntas e respostas úteis)

A reputação também é conhecida como um mecanismo de controle social ubíquo, espontâneo e altamente eficiente em sociedades naturais. Sua influência vai de ambientes competitivos, tais como mercados, aos corporativos, tais como empresas, organizações, instituições e comunidades.

Ademais a reputação atua em diferentes níveis de agência, individual e supra-individual. Ao nível supra-individual, diz respeito a grupos, comunidades, coletivos e entidades sociais abstratas (tais como empresas, corporações, países, culturas e mesmo civilizações). Ela afeta fenômenos em diferentes escalas, da vida cotidiana às relações entre nações.

A dúvida é **até que ponto a contagem de reputação visível a todos beneficiam a forma como usuários utilizam o site**. Visto que a reputação natural em nosso meio social é um pouco diferente do stackoverflow, no natural não existe este tipo de contagem, a reputação é algo abstrato e é um instrumento fundamental da ordem social, baseada em controle social espontâneo e distribuído.

Essa dúvida veio a partir de questões respondidas por pessoas com diferentes pontos de reputação, e que esses pontos acabam influenciando na escolha da melhor resposta. As vezes acontece de um usuário atribuir como melhor resposta a do usuário com maior quantidade de pontos de reputação, mesmo que a resposta não seja a mais satisfatória. Além disso, existe o efeito cascata, quando um usuário com alta quantidade de pontos de reputação influência outros usuários (positivamente ou negativamente) a tomarem uma decisão sem as vezes analisar a fundo a questão.

**Afinal, até que ponto a reputação ajuda a comunidade?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Como apontado por bfavaretto num comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1200/ate-que-ponto-a-reputacao-contribui-para-a-comunidade-alem-dos-privilegios#comment2745_1203), os "pontos de reputação" são responsáveis pelo aspecto da **gamificação** ([ludificação](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o), pros mais puristas) do Stack Overflow. Ele é considerado um aspecto central dessa plataforma (por exemplo, ver [esse post no coding horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/), ou [esse](http://blog.codinghorror.com/for-a-bit-of-colored-ribbon/)), e o principal objetivo parece ser mesmo estimular a participação - incentivando os usuários a se esforçarem para dar boas respostas e/ou formularem perguntas interessantes e úteis.

Dessa forma, ele deve ser visto simplesmente pelo que é: um sistema de pontuação. O fato dele se chamar "reputação" não quer dizer muita coisa, pois há pouca relação desse sistema com a reputação no mundo real (seja ela "natural" ou "auxiliada pela tecnologia"):

- Como bem apontado na pergunta, a reputação não funciona como uma contagem. Eu posso ser conhecido como um cara honesto ou como um ladrão, mas dificilmente alguém me consideraria "meio ladrão" ou "mais que ladrão". Ou eu posso ter fama de ser honesto nos negócios, mas trapaceiro nos jogos. Existem muitos rótulos que podem ser aplicados a um indivíduo, e embora muitos deles se estabeleçam a partir do seu histórico (ex.: compro desse cara há mais de 10 anos e ele nunca me vendeu um produto estragado) ainda tem pouco a ver com um valor numérico, linear, é uma coisa mais difusa.
- A reputação funciona como uma espécie de "pressão social": se eu sei que, após roubar, serei rotulado como "ladrão", e a consequência disso será maior dificuldade para fazer negócio com os outros (pois eles ficarão receosos a meu respeito), então isso me desincentiva a roubar. Junto com os demais meios de pressão social (moral - "roubar é errado"; institucional - "roubar é contra a lei"; segurança - "a porta está trancada"), a reputação ajuda a moldar o comportamento do indivíduo na vida em sociedade. Como no Stack Overflow os usuários votam em **ações** (perguntas, respostas) e não em **pessoas** (o usuário em si), essa pontuação não cumpre o papel da reputação nesse ambiente.

Há um ponto, entretanto, em que essa pontuação de fato cumpre o papel de reputação (seja pro bem ou pro mal). Como você apontou:

> Além disso, existe o efeito cascata, quando um usuário com alta quantidade de pontos de reputação influência outros usuários (positivamente ou negativamente) a tomarem uma decisão sem as vezes analisar a fundo a questão.

Um dos aspectos da gamificação do SE é a capacidade da comunidade de se auto-moderar: esses privilégios de fechar perguntas, votar para excluir postagens, editar posts alheios, ver e agir sobre flags (ainda que de forma limitada), etc não estão aí para "premiar" os usuários, para lhes dar "poder", mas sim pra reduzir o trabalho dos moderadores em tempo integral. Nem todo usuário tem interesse nisso, mas os que têm precisam no mínimo ter bastante familiaridade com o site para entender como suas regras funcionam, e qual a melhor forma de aplicá-las.

Como atingir esses privilégios leva tempo (é raro alguém ganhar [mais de mil upvotes numa única resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/520779), como [apontado por Anthony Accioly](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1203/215), o mais comum é ganhar uns poucos pontos [relativamente falando] por postagem, e eles irem se acumulando com o tempo), e o tempo de participação leva o usuário a ter maior contato com o site, daí conclui-se que "quem tem muitos pontos sabe como o site funciona" - e portanto está capacitado para ajudar a moderá-lo. Nem sempre isso é verdade, é claro, mas eu diria que é uma aproximação razoável.

E quanto aos usuários que não têm toda essa familiaridade e/ou não têm interesse em participar da moderação do site (preferindo se ater às perguntas e respostas)? Ou eles vão se abster disso ou - se compelidos a executar uma ação - seguir aqueles em cujo julgamento eles confiam. Na ausência de melhores referências, os pontos de reputação são a escolha natural... De novo, não é um sistema perfeito, mas é uma aproximação razoável, sendo raro um usuário com alta reputação avacalhar o sistema de moderação.

> As vezes acontece de um usuário atribuir como melhor resposta a do usuário com maior quantidade de pontos de reputação, mesmo que a resposta não seja a mais satisfatória.

Infelizmente esse é um problema que vai muito além do site, e é pervasivo na vida real: como avaliar alguém que tem mais conhecimento que você? Se eu preciso de um médico, por exemplo, como posso diferenciar um bom médico de um mau médico - sendo que mesmo o pior deles com certeza sabe muito mais de medicina do que eu? Não dá, e eu acabo sendo influenciado pela opinião de amigos e conhecidos. Mas se estes são leigos como eu, a opinião deles não deveria trazer muita confiança, afinal eles também não têm o conhecimento necessário para avaliar a competência de um médico...

Quando eu faço uma pergunta, normalmente é porque não sei a resposta. Se múltiplas respostas distintas me são apresentadas, e todas elas parecem resolver igualmente meu problema, como escolher uma delas como "certa"? Ou vai pela preferência (ex.: achei esse código mais "elegante"), ou se procura uma qualidade externa (solução A é mais concisa, solução B é mais performática), ou - se está com pressa e só quer uma solução e ponto - escolhe uma delas e encerra o assunto. O critério mais comum, pelo que observo, é "quem respondeu primeiro", mas escolher a resposta de quem tem mais reputação é também uma possibilidade...

Pessoalmente, quando tenho de escolher entre duas ou mais respostas igualmente boas, estabeleço um critério objetivo e o sigo. Mas se eu não tiver bons critérios, e for obrigado a me guiar pela experiência de quem responde, eu prefiro ler outras postagens do mesmo usuário pra "sentir" qual é a *expertise* dele. Dificilmente eu me guiaria pela pontuação - seja ela global, seja por tag, seja pela média (pontuação / nº posts) - pois sei que isso não significa muita coisa. Já que, assim como no exemplo do médico, quem deu a esse usuário uma alta pontuação não foram pessoas que sabem tanto ou mais que ele - mas sim usuários comuns, como eu, que provavelmente também são leigos no assunto que é de especialidade dele.

Answer (score 10):

**Partindo da [definição de reputação na central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).**

> A reputação é uma medição aproximada do grau de confiança da comunidade em você

Ao meu ver, na web as pessoas sempre encontram um meio de "medir" reputação. Sem um mecanismo de reputação oficial as pessoas começam a considerar medidas como número de posts (o que é uma medida ainda mais falha do que pontos).

O sistema de pontos é a prova de falhas? Absolutamente não.

Existe uma correlação entre a reputação de um usuário e a qualidade das suas respostas? Ao meu ver sim. Enquanto alguns usuários ganham caminhões de reputação com perguntas e respostas "engraçadas" ou "grandes sacadas", a maioria de nós ganhou reputação lentamente respondendo zilhões de questões com 2, 3 ou até mesmo nenhum voto. Quem está fazendo isso a muito tempo geralmente sabe como responder (veja que saber como responder não significa conhecer a melhor resposta).

Dito isso, cada usuário é livre para interpretar essa "medida de confiança" como bem entender.  Existem muitos usuários que não estão nem aí para os pontos, querem qualidade (é o meu caso; alguns alunos meus conseguiram 50k de reputação no SOE em dois anos, eu tenho o dobro do tempo e não alcancei 10k). Alguns outros querem realmente ajudar e ganham muitos pontos por consequência. E é claro que há os que gostam de "jogar" e/ou de influenciar.

Se a atitude de um usuário (ou de um grupo) prejudicar a comunidade deixe-nos saber, independente da reputação dos usuários envolvidos. A Stack Exchange está de olho, o Gabe está de olho, e sim, usuários mais experientes (que não são uma "panela" uniforme; nós discordamos em muitas coisas) estão de olho.

---

Quanto a mencionada tendência de votar em usuários com reputação maior, isso é uma grande bobagem.

Para pegar um exemplo específico: O [Daniel C. Sobral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/99/daniel-c-sobral) possui uma conta com pouco mais de 1k reputação por aqui no momento. No SOE ele possui uma conta [com mais de 150k de reputação](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel-c-sobral). Ele não é uma referência menos confiável sobre Scala ou Java por aqui do que por lá, nem é menos genial por aqui do que por lá. Mesmo que ele não tivesse 150k de reputação em um site irmão, lendo as respostas do Sobral fica claro que ele é um especialista no assunto (além de um grande influenciador e entusiasta de Scala). Reputação não deve ser imã de votos, qualidade é o que conta! :).

Comment: Tem mais uma coisa: a reputação é o ponto central de todo o mecanismo de *gamificação* do site, e um grande incentivo para muita gente participar. Deixar de exibir a reputação publicamente com certeza afastaria muita gente (principalmente entre os que respondem).