# sugestão sobre votos

Tags: debate, moderação, voto-contra

Olá pessoal tenho algumas considerações sobre os votos...
Vejo que as vezes rola uma 'proteção' entre quem votou e recebeu, como uma troca de favor.

Certo dia rolou uma pergunta amplamente vaga e por final foi trancada, mas o autor citava outro usuario como exemplo de resposta e o usuario deu up-vote aparentemente como troca de favor.

> Poderia haver um limite como, quem recebeu um voto de fulano, não pode votar em fulano durante algum tempo - apenas sugestão, mas algo para coibir a troca de votos

> Para aceitar `voto negativo` deveria haver necessidade de justificativa, mesmo que apenas para moderação acompanhar, desta forma, quem se sentir prejudicado tem a chance de recorrer contra uma injustiça.

São apenas algumas sugestões para o bom andamento da comunidade e preservar os bons votos.
Sintam-se a vontade para compartilhar outras ideias.

Comment: `o usuario deu upvote` isso é impossível afirmar. Ou você tem alguma prova que possa mostrar?

Comment: & -1 porque hoje tá fazendo muito calor . . . . *(exemplo de justificativa)* . . . . .

Comment: Meu -1 aqui é exatamente por causa do que diz o botão do -1. Se você pegar todas as discussões que já houveram sobre isso no meta principal e imprimir, você teria um livro com várias vezes mais palavras do que a Bíblia. E o consenso é sempre o mesmo de que essa proposta é uma péssima ideia.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Até que ponto os votos são "controlados"?

Exceto quando há exageros, inibir um usuário de votar acarreta diretamente em restringir a liberdade individual.

O modelo do SO é mais democrático, no sentido de que respeita a decisão do indivíduo sobre a melhor forma de votar.

O que geralmente se faz é apenas orientar segundo alguns critérios mais adequados.

Por outro lado, para evitar os excessos, o sistema possui alguns mecanismos de controle:

- Há um limite do número de votos diários, então um usuário não pode votar infinitamente nos demais.
- O sistema detecta votos em massa automaticamente, revertendo-os geralmente durante a noite.
- Os moderadores conseguem analisar tendências de votos, então se um usuário começar a privilegiar apenas um "amigo", ele poderá ser notificado sobre este comportamento e, em certos casos, até punido.

Embora possa haver pequenas "injustiças" (acho que na maioria das vezes não seja o caso), em geral isso acaba sendo praticamente irrelevante comparando com os usuários que consistentemente produzem bom conteúdo.

## Votos contrários devem exigir justificativas?

Esse assunto já foi discutido algumas vezes, em perguntas ou nas entrelinhas, no SOpt ou mesmo lá fora. Veja as seguintes questões:

- [Voto negativo sem justificativa é válido?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/652/227)
- [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/227)

Realmente é ruim quando recebemos votos negativos sem justificativa, principalmente quando temos alguma segurança sobre a qualidade da reposta.

Mas este é um direito que cabe aos usuários. Muitas vezes é patente que a resposta é ruim. Outras vezes os usuários ficam divididos.

Além disso, os votos são anônimos, então obrigar uma justificativa iria inibir muitas pessoas de votarem.

## Considerações

Não estou oferecendo respostas definitivas aqui, apenas o ponto de vista de alguém que tem acompanhando o SOpt desde o seu nascimento. Mas espero ter esclarecido alguns pontos.

Comment: `obrigar uma justificativa iria inibir muitas pessoas de votarem`, eu acho que torna necessário o minimo de conhecimento... já que a proposta é ajudar, negativar sem motivos não contribui em nada. Enfim, são apenas sugestões.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Ao contrário, negativar contribui para mover as respostas ruins para baixo e as boas para cima. A proposta do site é ajudar, mas a proposta dos votos é outra. Eu sei que pode ser ruim em alguns casos, mas não acho que ninguém deva ser obrigado a ajudar o autor da resposta para poder votar.

Comment: também ninguém é obrigado a responder uma duvida, mas fazem por prazer e/ou pontos. E se o voto negativo somasse ponto mediante justificativa seria uma forma de incentivar a melhoria de uma questão. Acho que fomentaria bastante debates sobre todas as questões que de alguma forma abrem espaço para duvidas. Concorda?

Comment: @PapaCharlie O problema é que somente colocar um comentário em si não significa que a pessoa está tentando ajudar. Muitos começariam a criticar detalhes das respostas onde não há real necessidade e não haveria como o sistema distinguir uma real ajuda de alguém caçando pontos. Se houvesse uma forma de fazer isso seria excelente. Outro ponto que esqueci de mencionar é que votos negativos custam 1 ponto da reputação, então já é uma forma de barrar usuários que não tem pontuação.

Comment: Mas essa é a questão, muitos postam qualquer coisa e sabem que estão dando uma resposta muito aquém do esperado, e negativar uma resposta como essa não vai causar danos ao autor... Já uma resposta coerente que receba um motivo, poderia dar a chance do autor recorrer ao ponto perdido, caso a justificativa não seja válida.

Answer (score 6):

> Poderia haver um limite como, quem recebeu um voto de fulano, não pode
>   votar em fulano durante algum tempo - apenas sugestão, mas algo para
>   coibir a troca de votos

É verdade, poderia haver esse limite. Mas o risco de ele acabar sendo injusto e/ou prejudicar a experiência daqueles participantes que votam de forma "honesta"<sup>*</sup> é simplesmente grande demais. Não acho que seja possível ter dados estatísticos a esse respeito, mas a minha intuição me diz que *a grande maioria da comunidade* não vota em conteúdo olhando o nome de quem produziu. E mesmo que o limite existisse, nada impediria os mal-intencionados procurassem por formas alternativas de atingir o mesmo resultado (por exemplo, 3 ou 4 partipantes votando entre si indiretamente). Assim, um limite desses seria provavelmente mais danoso do que útil.

*<sup>as aspas aqui se devem a ser discutível o fato de que fazer troca de votos é ilegal - embora isso seja, mais claramente, de pouca ética.</sup>

> Para aceitar voto negativo deveria haver necessidade de justificativa,
>   mesmo que apenas para moderação acompanhar, desta forma, quem se
>   sentir prejudicado tem a chance de recorrer contra uma injustiça.

Idealmente quem comenta deseja ajudar a melhorar o conteúdo. Porém, quem vota está apenas contribuindo com uma indicação do seu julgamento *pessoal e subjetivo* a respeito de atributos qualitativos do conteúdo. *Essas não são atuações necessariamente ligadas*. A primeira, por exemplo, não tem muito impacto para a comunidade a não ser que o OP entenda e aceite a sugestão/crítica e altere o conteúdo. Novamente não acho possível obter tais estatísticas, mas provavelmente a maioria dos leitores não vagueiam por uma lista enorme de comentários, focando seu esforço no conteúdo principal (que é a pergunta ou resposta). Já a segunda tem um impacto [estigmérgico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigmergy) e é diretamente útil como um medidor da aprovação ou rejeição *de toda a comunidade* a um certo conteúdo. É natural esperar que perguntas mais/menos votadas atraiam atenção e, consequentemente, recebam mais votos positivos/negativos. É justamente essa a grande sacada do sistema de votos. Aliás, um grande número de votos pra qualquer lado é sinal de que o conteúdo ali é relevante, seja como um bom ou um mal exemplo.

Enfim, você mesmo não chegou a cogitar haver a necessidade de justificar votos positivos, porque talvez seja mais claro enxergar que nesse caso eles não são realmente necessários para acompanhar o voto. Porém alguém poderia argumentar que uma pergunta indicando -49 mas tendo recebido 50 votos negativos e 1 positivo mereceria uma justificativa do voto positivo, não? Mereceria sim, o comentário seria provavelmente bem recebido, poderia proporcionar uma discussão interessante sobre o conteúdo... ou não.

Como o voto é subjetivo, talvez quem votou positivamente nesse caso desejou apenas expressar o seu contentamento por ter aprendido algo, e requerer que o indivíduo comente serviria apenas para ocupar espaço na página. Se quem votou era amigo do OP e ficou triste por ele, bom, paciência. Ainda assim, claramente o voto solitário não mudou a opinião geral da comunidade. Isso somente seria alcançado por meio de argumentação, o que significa comentar, seja lá ou aqui.