# Como comentar perguntas/respostas ruins da forma correta?

Tags: debate, moderação

Recentemente tivemos um caso, pra quem esteve ativo nesses últimos 3 dias, de um usuário que não soube lidar bem com críticas sobre a pergunta dele, e hoje "quase" (vamos ver o degringolar da história) aconteceu o mesmo: [A cada N repetições exibir X no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9822/a-cada-n-repeti%C3%A7%C3%B5es-exibir-x-no-php)

Bom, sempre segui essa cartilha: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/654/14262, se eu voto down, e não vejo um comentário para positivar, tento explicar o que vi de errado, mas nem sempre o usuário entende como uma crítica construtiva, e às vezes a negativação acaba por piorar a situação. Entendo que críticas devem ser levadas por um lado comunitário, fazendo o usuário e a própria comunidade evoluir, mas também entendo o lado dos usuários que se sentem indignados com as críticas. No começo eu também cheguei a agir [meio com indignação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47854/o-que-s%C3%A3o-n%C3%BAmeros-de-nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o-decimal-hexadecimal-e-octal/47855#47855) com críticas construtivas, mesmo tendo preferido não me estressar como outros usuários fazem :P

Existem usuários mais novos que entendem essas críticas e realmente melhoram com o tempo, mas ainda tem muitos outros que não entendem e acabam atacando outros usuários ou a comunidade. A meu ver apenas não aprenderam a usar as ferramentas do SO, ou não entenderam a filosofia da rede.

Vale salientar que existem casos que a pessoa realmente se sente um floco de neve.

Enfim, qual é a melhor forma de comentar perguntas/respostas ruins? De forma a não ofender, e de forma que faça o usuário entender os pontos que devem ser melhorados, claramente.

Sinto que muitas vezes apontar o `tour`, o `MCVE` ou o `ask` muitas vezes não resultam em nada ;/

Comment: Por isso que nem eu sigo essa cartilha :D Eu vejo se o usuário está a fim de evoluir, ou até de debater saudavelmente se ele realmente tem ponto pra levantar. Se a pessoa é teimosa, mal educada ou incapaz de manter uma conversa decente, fica só o negativo.

Comment: Tour, MVCE e outros links são complementos para um melhor entendimento do modelo, nesse caso indique algum dos links e deixe um breve e direto comentário (personalizado) sobre o que pode ser melhorado imediatamente.

Comment: diria que aquela resposta esta _deprecated_ então? :P

Comment: Apenas um detalhe sobre o "floco de neve": a brilhante resposta do OnoSendai que explicava isso foi deletada junto com a pergunta, então quem não viu aquilo, provavelmente não vai entender a ideia.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Não exatamente, porque nem todo mundo precisa fazer igual a mim e eu sigo ela pra quem quer ser um bom(a) menino(a).

Comment: Isso é questão de estilo... Eu geralmente vou na linha do @rray, os links são para dar subsídio; essa é uma técnica para tornar o comentário mais "impessoal". É claro que, apesar das nossas melhores intenções volta e meia algo assim acontece. As vezes por desconhecimento da parte do usuário, as vezes por diferenças de personalidade e as vezes por ter pego alguém em um dia ruim (acontece). Se é usuário novo eu geralmente sinalizo e deixo a exclusão acontecer naturalmente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pessoalmente eu adoto a seguinte postura:

1. **Com educação**, se começar dizendo que não gosta ou não concorda, ou sair negativando "do nada", quem recebe o comentário/negativação acaba ficando com mais dúvida.
2. **Argumento com base em fontes técnicas** e não em outras perguntas/comentários/opiniões. Já recebi comentários sem "pé-nem-cabeça", e nem por isso entrei na onda da "briga de opinião".
3. Outro ponto é indicar no comentário que a pergunta deveria ser colocada em outro Forum, porque **as vezes a pergunta não está ruim, está apenas no lugar errado**.
4. **Pessoalmente, eu parei de negativar**. Se a questão/resposta está muito ruim, eu simplesmente escrevo: "melhor revisar o texto e conceito, senão pode ser negativado". e passo adiante.