# Votos negativos por "Haters"

Tags: debate

Gostaria de entender como o SO monitora os votos negativos. Vez ou outra aparece um doido que sai dando voto negativo em TODAS as perguntas, e são todas mesmo, porque eu entro em cada uma, e elas as vezes tem até votos positivos, mas estão la com -1 de voto negativo, como nesse exato momento, se você entrar em qualquer uma das perguntas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É... São doidos.

Comment: Não me parece nenhum doido não, pode ser que seja, mas é o seguinte, olhei quase todas perguntas (a maioria foi removida inclusive), ou seja para quem tem mais experiencia no site, sabe notar falta de coisas como um bom MCVE (exemplo do problema que possa ser reproduzido), falta de um bom titulo, problemas de erro de digitação, etc. Então quem votou sendo uma ou mais pessoas, me parece que avaliou muito bem, downvote não é coisa maligna, é para avaliar e indicar que tem problemas, lógico que tem uma duzia de pessoas que sabemos quem é que usam os downvotes contra seus desafetos...

Comment: ... mas nem tudo é possivel ser resolvido :/, infelizmente é esperar os haters criarem maturidade e colocarem o orgulho burro de lado, também temos muitos casos (são muitos mesmos) de pessoas que dão upvotes em perguntas respostas que não merecem, eu diria que é uma quantidade de pessoas muito superior a quem dá downvotes gratuitos, eu vejo muitos upvotes em postagens horriveis, inclusive em respostas desastrosas e/ou erradas.

Comment: Para justificar o que o @GuilhermeNascimento comentou, o fato de ocorrer muito mais upvote injustamente do que downvote pode ser porque, dando downvote, você perde 1 de pontuação, dando upvote pode-se dar a entender que você é participativo pelo seu perfil... A tendencia é sim você ter muito mais votos positivo do que negativos no seu perfil, mas você verá muitos usuários com uma porcentagem de votos a favor infinitamente superior a de votos negativos.

Comment: @MarceloBoni também é em parte isto, mas é apenas parte, boa parte dos upvotes gratuitos é realmente porque as pessoas pensam que UPVOTE é LIKE, ao invés de avaliarem o conteudo e testarem de verdade e no minimo checarem se aquela de fato é uma boa solução :(

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se avaliou por erros de digitação, títulos ruins... Não seria melhor ter editado, comentado algo e melhorado as perguntas? Com seu mesmo exemplo, vejo pessoas fazendo do DOWNVOTE um DISLIKE. Sempre prefiro tentar salvar as perguntas. Às vezes "perco parte do tempo" na fila de análises inserindo comentários específicos nas publicações, ao invés daqueles engessados. Já houve discussões a respeito, não quero iniciar mais uma. Além disso concordo com o que você disse, mas acho que precisa ter alguém pra criar um ponto de vista oposto...

Comment: ... Ainda compactuo com a ideia de [comentar e tentar ajudar o AP a salvar a publicação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/654/5043).

Comment: @bio não fui eu quem avaliou, estou só colocando as motivações possiveis, tem usuários antigos que ainda insistem em titulos de suporte técnico com o uso de "DUVIDA COM X", "Ajuda com Y", não tem como ficarmos corrigindo todos titulos e nem estou dizendo que eu mesmo dou downvote porque o titulo é ruim, estou comentando o que é algo possivel por parte de quem avaliou as postagens, estou apenas tentando dar um norte.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento *"boa parte dos upvotes gratuitos é realmente porque as pessoas pensam que UPVOTE é LIKE"* concordo contigo. Pode ter uma pergunta absurdamente inútil para a maioria, por exemplo "Preciso compilar um programa no windows 7 com SP1 rodando no VMware V1.01, 32bits numa máquina dual core". Cara é totalmente específico (só um exemplo), mas se a pergunta for bem elaborada, MCVE, exemplos, links, etc, ela merece um upvote, porque o usuário cumpriu seu papel: leu o tutorial, elaborou uma boa pergunta, e isso não significa que a pergunta seja "boa para a comunidade" como um todo

Comment: @RicardoPontual não estou falando de um caso que mereça, mesmo quando muito especifico, estou falando do entendimento das pessoas que não executam o códigos de respostas ou pegam perguntas repetitivas de mero suporte técnico que ganham upvote como se fosse LIKE, ou seja não especifiquei nenhuma pergunta que tenha ocorrido isso, justamente para ser imparcial e falarmos do problema e não de perguntas especificas. É um problema antigo na comunidade.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendi, o que quero dizer é que, como você mencionou, vejo as pessoas usando o upvote como um "like", e não para  prestigiar perguntas bem elaboradas

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim, mas o problema não é falar do que esta bem elaborado, mas sim do uso dos upvotes, como é usado, não estou falando de conteudo ou tipo de conteudo justamente para não sermos especificos e nem apontar para nada, estou falando do comportamento de uso de uma ferramenta. É algo que leva um tempo na comunidade para entender como ocorre.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Há um mecanismo que tenta identificar sozinho quando há algum ataque a um usuário. Obviamente ele pega casos triviais. Os demais só um moderador analisando manualmente se tiver conhecimento.

Estes casos são mais complicados de avaliar. Você pode afirmar que foi a mesma pessoa? Eu não posso, mesmo tendo acesso a mais informação que você. Tem certeza que os votos não foram merecidos? Não vi todas e não posso avaliar, mas tem coisa ruim ali mesmo. Infelizmente temos recebido muita coisa ruim e os usuários vão cansando de tentar ajudar tanta gente descomprometida com o próprio problema.