# Porque negativaram minhas perguntas?

Tags: suporte, voto-contra

A pessoa nem se esforça em explicar o motivo, gostaria de entender:

[Como relacionar dois domínios diferentes para utilizar webview no app?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/421530/como-relacionar-dois-dom%c3%adnios-diferentes-para-utilizar-webview-no-app)

[Como fazer um regex para tratar o texto desta forma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422090/como-fazer-um-regex-para-tratar-o-texto-desta-forma)

Comment: Sinceramente, a primeira pergunta na minha leitura é tão confusa que merecia um voto de fechamento por falta de clareza. A segunda questão o título apenas indica que você quer fazer algo com regex, mas na real talvez seu problema não seja nem esse (lembra problema XY). Então, assim, considero que ela esteja mal redigida nesse ponto, em que você não expressa qual a sua necessidade (apenas diz que há uma necessidade).

Comment: Relacionada: [Voto negativo sem justificativa é válido?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/652/5878)

Comment: A primeira pergunta só está querendo uma solução para a nova regra do google play, para um app que usa dois logins, um para nativo e outro para webview, o que tem de confuso nisso?

Comment: A segunda, uma solução em regex para fornecer uma resposta única para 3 casos diferentes.

Comment: A segunda realmente demandaria um comentário acompanhado de voto de fechamento. É um problema XY. [Não se usa expressões regulares para avaliar HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/5878). Principalmente quando se tem HTML "aleatórios". Somente o fato de "ter a necessidade" de inserir um parágrafo em branco no DOM é um indicativo que o que se pede é uma medida paliativa do problema, que conhecemos por gambiarra. A pergunta não faz sentido, mas deve-se presumir que o AP desconhece o fato descrito, por isso demandaria o comentário. Não sei opinar sobre a primeira.

Comment: Não está claro, na segunda, o que é entrada e resposta correspondente.

Comment: Mas @Woss, não sou eu quem define as regras da empresa, se a empresa quer uma medida paliativa, eu tenho que fazer, há "n" maneiras melhores de resolver isso, o conteúdo do banco de dados está desestruturado, e eu preciso alinhar o texto na tela... a solução resolve o problema, e foi a forma que foi definido para fazer... Você acha que eu não apresentei soluções melhores, tipo editar o texto do banco de dados? Sim, mas ninguém quer adotar esta medida...

Comment: @IvanFerrer, já tentou montar numa árvore externa ao DOM principal e fazer o processamento deste DOM secundário? (Phantom-DOM, eu acho)

Comment: @IvanFerrer Mas percebe que esse tipo de conteúdo será útil apenas no seu caso, que "realmente precisa" fazer dessa forma? Se por acaso alguém cair na sua pergunta e ela estiver respondida como você quer o usuário pode julgar que essa é uma forma válida e replicar a gambiarra. Não é saudável para a comunidade. Se você tem HTML **aleatórios**, eles não são **regulares**, logo é impossível utilizar **expressões regulares**. Não há contra argumento nisso.

Comment: Também daria para fazer ajustes no CSS, acontece que o conteúdo nem existia até então no banco de dados, era tudo arquivo HTML, tivemos que importar tudo para o o banco, e ta tudo em formato HTML, não há uma alternativa melhor para não perder a formatação... eu sei exatamente onde aperta o problema... não há magica para isso. Já estamos fazendo mais do que é possível aqui.

Comment: Só precisa por um parágrafo que ta tudo certo...

Comment: Eu tive esse experiência com perguntas feitas em português.
Pode ser que sua pergunta esteja mal formulada ou até que seja algo fácil de se resolver na documentação.
Na melhor das opções, missclick :)

Comment: Tem um monte de coisa pra falar e eu tenho certeza que todo mundo vai tentar explicar tudo certinho pra você. Mas, basicamente, é o seguinte: Talvez as perguntas estejam confusas, ou mal escritas, ou fora de escopo, não sei. Eu também acho que quem negativa deveria dizer o porquê, mas isso não é feito e já tem um mooooonte de discussão sobre isso desde os primórdios do SOPT (e talvez dos outros sites da rede). Além disso, mesmo numa pergunta ótima ainda pode rolar um negativo, sei lá o motivo, às vezes acontece. Você vai precisar ficar de boa com isso e relevar. Principalmente se suas [+]

Comment: [+] perguntas estiverem ok e permanecerem sem nenhum voto de fechamento. Quando alguém comentar um problema ou votar pra fechar sua pergunta, tente entender o ponto exposto e assumir a boa vontade da outra pessoa, no mais apenas releve e lembre-se que são apenas pontinhos de internet.

Comment: Não acho que são grandes merecedoras de downvotes, mas noto que você tem um problema as vezes, mas é opinião pessoal minha, você geralmente não vai direto ao ponto e/ou não apresenta algo "palpável" (geralmente executável), as pessoas ficam com receio de terem ou não entendido a sua duvida, eu não vou afirmar que não estão claras, dá pra entender, mas depois de ler umas 2 vezes achei compreensível, vou ser sincero...

Comment: ...eu (eu mesmo) até hoje tenho dificuldade em elaborar boas perguntas, mas também já vi muitas perguntas ruins com +4 (ou até mais), hoje eu consigo perguntar, geralmente ganho bastante views, mas pouco feedback, creio que se conseguir ir direto ao ponto (melhorar a escrita neste sentido) vai ter maiores resultados, como disse, as vezes algum detalhe (no caso google) como imagem, ou em caso de códigos, um StackSnippet ajuda MUITO!

Comment: Eu nem estava aqui hoje, nem estou muito a fim de ver o que ocorreu,. Eu tenho dado quase 40 negativos por dia, quase todos os dias assim. O conteúdo está muito ruim. Ficou virtualmente impossível dar tanto *feedback*, inclusive porque em geral começa gerar discussões, reclamações, vingança. A comunidade tá mal em vários sentidos. Hoje devo fazer uma postagem para ajudar geral, mas acho que ajudará pouco. Será algo que muita gente não vai gostar, mas ela vai na mesma linha das perguntas ruins, o pessoal joga qualquer porcaria aqui e exige esforço de quem for responder...

Comment: ... e receberá um ajuda genérica e que demandará esforço que quem pergunta.

Comment: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Comment: Acho que tem mesmo um perfil de usuário que é meio preguiçoso, que não se esforça para elaborar uma boa pergunta, ou tem um critério muito baixo de expor o problema de forma compreensível. Eu geralmente, as vezes coloco minhas perguntas até meio redundante propositadamente, porque tem muitos leitores que não sabem interpretar texto. Daí eu repito palavras, para facilitar a compreensão. [+]

Comment: [+] Tem os que são preguiçosos para entender a pergunta também, ou está sem muita vontade de ler, sei lá... faz uma busca visual por cima, e já acha que não dá pra entender nada... Tem casos que só lendo tudo é possível entender... e isso gera pontos negativos de forma equivocada.

Comment: Agora tem muitas perguntas que são vagas, mal escritas e não passam nenhuma informação relevante para ser ajudado...Esse eu negativo também.

Comment: Cara eu to ficando puto com isso já, faço várias perguntas aqui e o povo simplesmente votam negativo sem dizer o motivo, oras, como vou saber o que ta errado se nao me falam o motivo e apenas negativam? A pergunta é simples e fazem tempestade em copo d'água. A comunidade em vez de te ajudar simplesmente faz as coisas e fodase vc? não te falam um motivo? outro dia abri uma pergunta o cara foi la e fechou alegando que a pergunta não estava clara o suficiente, ja tinha falado a minha duvida, ja tinha postado meu codigo, querem mais o que?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para oficializar a minha opinião:

> Como relacionar dois domínios diferentes para utilizar webview no app?

Não tenho conhecimento suficiente do assunto para opinar sobre o nível da pergunta e o mérito/demérito do voto, então me absterei.

> Como fazer um regex para tratar o texto desta forma?

É um caso que eu acho complicado porque a pergunta é "ruim", mas não por demérito do autor, mas sim um possível desconhecimento dele (e é provavelmente por isso que ele está perguntando). Vejo várias pessoas dando o negativo em perguntas assim por não julgá-las úteis por pedir como faz algo que não deveria ser feito. Em uma relação simples, seria como se alguém perguntasse "como consigo fixar um prego utilizando um serrote?".

Teria como responder mostrando como fazer isso? Sim. Deveríamos fazer isso? Não vejo porquê. O melhor seria responder mostrando que para fixar um prego o melhor é utilizar um martelo. A pergunta, mesmo ruim porque partiu de uma premissa errada pode gerar um conteúdo que é útil para a comunidade.

A sua pergunta ainda tem um detalhe que colabora na análise de baixa qualidade pois solicita como fazer algo que potencialmente nem deveria ser feito de uma maneira errada. Então ao invés de apenas perguntar "como fixar o prego com um serrote" você estaria perguntando "como fixar um imã na geladeira com um prego usando um serrote?". Ainda é possível dar a mesma resposta de antes, mostrando como pregar usando um serrote ou mostrar que o melhor é utilizar o martelo... mas realmente é necessário pregar um imã na geladeira?

De forma mais clara, a sua pergunta solicita como pode inserir um parágrafo em branco utilizando REGEX. Uma resposta seria mostrar que REGEX não é a melhor solução para analisar HTML, como já discutido em [Por que Regex não deve ser utilizado para tratar HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/5878) Mas o fato de necessitar inserir um parágrafo em branco para **contornar** um problema não é claro (seria o "pregar o imã"). Inserir um parágrafo em branco no DOM fere a semântica do documento e para todos os fins é uma solução paliativa; melhor seria resolver a fonte do problema.

Dito isso, acho que a segunda **pode** merecer o voto negativo por não ser clara quanto à segunda parte, da necessidade de inserir o parágrafo em branco ([O que é o "problema XY"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878)), mas de qualquer forma deveria ser fechada como não clara e comentado sobre o fato de que REGEX não é legal para HTML, principalmente quando o HTML é "aleatório".

Supondo que a inserção do parágrafo em branco "resolva" um problema de espaçamento entre os elementos atuais no DOM, a pergunta não deveria ser "como inserir um parágrafo em branco", mas sim "como remover o espaçamento" e assim permitir que a resposta possa ser, por exemplo, em CSS resolvendo a fonte do problema.

Comment: Tem esse artigo do [Codding Horror:Análise de HTML da maneira Cthulhu](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) dando apoio a sua análise.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Não se esqueça da resposta clássica/mítica/definitiva sobre o tema: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: @hkotsubo essa é melhor. xD