# Perguntas pedindo indicação de ferramentas online

Tags: debate

Recentemente [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39415/site-com-problemas-diversos-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) foi fechada porque diversos usuários consideraram-na fora do escopo. Eu não entendi o motivo e segui o link para a central de ajuda, onde encontrei a seguinte [descrição do escopo do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> se a sua pergunta tem a ver com...
>
> - um problema específico de programação
> - um algorítmo de software
> - ferramentas comuns entre programadores
> - problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
> - dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software
>
> … então este é o lugar certo para fazer sua pergunta

Dei uma buscada e encontrei [outra pergunta pedindo recursos online](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9889/programar-online-em-c/9892#9892), fechada há alguns meses como sendo baseada em opiniões.

No meu entendimento, as duas perguntas em questão cairia na categoria "ferramentas comuns". Nenhuma delas pede opiniões nem abre espaço para subjetividade, elas especificamente pedem links para sites que ofereçam ferramentas com uma funcionalidade específica.

O bigown [comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39415/site-com-problemas-diversos-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o#comment77086_39415) que a comunidade é contra respostas contendo apenas links, chamando atenção para [esta discussão no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links), da qual eu já estava ciente. Destaco alguns trechos:

> Respostas com links são ótimas. Não entenda errado. O problema aparece
> quando as respostas têm apenas links.
>
> (…)
>
> Se a "resposta" só tem o link e ele deixa de existir ou não tem mais a
> mesma informação, a resposta passa estar errada.
>
> (…)
>
> Links sozinhos não ajudam outros desenvolvedores ou curiosos que têm
> um problema semelhante. Eles vão procurar no Google e encontrar apenas
> as respostas que tenham conteúdo relevante para ser indexado. Um link
> não tem conteúdo que ajudam os buscadores.
>
> (…)
>
> Faça pelo menos um resumo do que tem no link. Forneça algum contexto
> para o link. Diga porque o link é útil, reforce alguma parte, cite,
> através do uso justo, o que é mais relevante. Pequenas diferenças
> podem fazer toda diferença.

Eu concordo com os pontos acima (inclusive [segui essa lógica na minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39418/7982) e tentei expandir um pouco minha resposta). Entretanto acho absurdo aplicar a lógica de que respostas contendo apenas links são problemáticas quando temos perguntas que explicitamente pedem links.

Claro que isso pode gerar problemas com links mortos, mas qualquer pergunta pedindo links vai gerar uma resposta sujeita a isso.

Mas temo estar interpretando mal tanto a pergunta quanto a discussão do meta. Minhas perguntas são:

1. É consenso que essas perguntas devem ser fechadas *pelos motivos listados*? Me parece que elas foram fechadas por pedir links, mas em nenhum lugar encontrei uma regra específica contra isso.
2. Existe algum motivo para perguntas pedindo links serem indesejáveis? Se forem, acho que isso deveria ser listado e explicado na seção relevante da central de ajuda.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como podemos lidar com as “listas”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/819/3117)

Comment: A pergunta que originou esta discussão ainda tinha outro problema, somente links: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links

Comment: @bigown Esse link do meta se refere a respostas, é essa a razão da minha pergunta número 2.

Comment: Também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-quest%C3%B5es-de-recomenda%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: O motivo de perguntas que pedem links serem indesejadas é justamente o tipo de resposta que elas terão (que tem os problemas que você já mencionou).

Comment: @bfavaretto, esta pergunta não seria duplicata? Creio que isto já foi discutido antes... Acho que a única novidade aqui é a oficialização (central de ajuda) do fato: *Shopping Questions não são bem-vindas*. . . . kadu, respondendo ao seu comentário lá na resposta, sim acho que deviamos abrir um pedido de novo recurso com isso; mas antes gostaria de ouvir a opinião dos moderadores e do community manager sobre a aplicação do princípio [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) aqui no SOpt.

Comment: Tou chegando atrasado pra conversa, mas pra mim a pergunta é um exemplo de vários problemas, não apenas um. Ela é baseada em opiniões, pede referências externas que vão ficar obsoletas, tratam de um problema subjetivo e completamente fora do padrão Q&A. Acho que há que se fazer uma separação entre dúvida legítima (e a do autor até é uma duvida legítima) e pergunta pra ser respondida no SOpt, pois uma não implica a outra. O autor tem sim uma dúvida, mas o canal adequado é outro. Como bem dizem por aí, site que você faz uma pergunta e recebe um monte de links de volta, já tem outros bem famosos.

Comment: PS: Acho perfeitamente válido alguém ajudar o autor, inclusive incentivo a responder a dúvida nos comments, e a comunidade fechar a pergunta normalmente. É um procedimento que resolve o problema pontual sem distorcer a coisa toda. O Autor resolve o problema imediato, o site não fica com coisa torta pendurada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que o maior problema com o tipo de pergunta *específico* desse caso - uma lista de coisas que atendam aos requisitos X - é a obsolescência das respostas. Há algumas coisas que não cabem perfeitamente no nosso modelo, como a definição da *melhor resposta*. Seria a que contém mais indicações? A que fornece uma descrição básica de cada uma das indicações? A que indica a coisa mais famosa ou mais utilizada?

São problemas de fato mas que podem ser resolvidos, de uma forma ou de outra, dentro da engine do Stack Exchange. A nossa engine não foi feita para apenas um tipo fixo de pergunta, e é adaptada para diversos formatos específicos, dentro das diferentes comunidades.

Além disso, esperar que todas as perguntas no Stack Exchange tenham *apenas uma resposta claramente superior* é diminuir e limitar a capacidade de uma comunidade de fazer, e responder, boas perguntas.

O Grace Note argumenta muito bem em uma [resposta no Meta World Builders SE](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/110/136):

> That's the key here, it's isolating what problem is being asked, and then you judge the validity of the question based on that problem. If the problem's scope is improperly sized or is otherwise unfit for the site, that makes it a poor question, not the fact that the question requests a list of items.
>
> ---
>
> Essa é a chave. É necessário **isolar o problema da pergunta, e determinar a validade da pergunta com base nesse problema**. Se o escopo do problema não cair dentro do que é apropriado para o site, **isso** torna a pergunta ruim. Não o fato de ela pedir uma lista de itens.

Eu vejo que o problema da pergunta é bastante claro, bem especificado e nada subjetivo. Ela não pede por nenhuma avaliação pessoal, ou características passíveis de discussão. O escopo não é muito grande, nem muito pequeno. A pergunta é *útil*, tanto para o autor quanto para outras pessoas, e dificilmente vai se tornar obsoleta em alguns meses, ao contrário das famigeradas *shopping questions*.

Há uma diferença entre peguntas que requerem uma "lista de respostas" ("Qual sua biblioteca de datas favorita?"; "Preciso comprar uma placa de vídeo") e perguntas que requerem "respostas que são listas". Um problema válido pode ter como resposta uma lista de itens e não há nada de errado com isso.

Ainda da resposta da Grace:

> **"List question" is basically a loaded buzzword. There is no proper construct, nor are these questions inherently a bad fit for our engine.**
>
> There's a very wide misconception spread by this term which causes any and every question which has multiple answers, especially that they may form a list of more than 2 items, to be condemned as this horrible thing called a "list question". It's partially rooted in the idea of there needing to be a single definitive answer to any question. Neither of these are actual things. Being a list isn't a problem in itself. And the realization of this fact is that while there are a specific kind of problematic list (itemized lists, which were the subject of a number of our blog posts), you can often transform these into a non-problematic sort of list with a little effort.
>
> ---
>
> **"Pergunta de lista" é basicamente um jargão sem sentido. Não existe uma definição formal e nossa engine é perfeitamente capaz de suportá-las.**
>
> Este termo cultiva uma noção errada de que toda e qualquer pergunta que tenha múltiplas respostas, especialmente as que contém listas de 2 ou mais itens, devem ser rejeitadas e taxadas de "perguntas de listas". Isso vem da idéia de que é necessário que as perguntas tenham apenas uma resposta definitiva, mas nada disso é verdade. Listas não são problemas apenas por serem listas. Entender isso é perceber que mesmo que existam tipos específicos de listas que são ruins (perguntas que pedem múltiplas respostas, sem que nenhuma sirva como resposta por si só, que já foram abordadas em diversos posts no nosso blog)<sup>1</sup>, é possível transformá-las em boas listas sem muito esforço.
>
> ---
>
> <sup><sup>1</sup> Tive dúvidas sobre o que o Grace quis dizer com "itemized lists", então perguntei. Essa foi a resposta que ela me deu:</sup>
>
> > <sup>What I use the term "itemized list" to refer to, is a space of questions where this concept breaks down. That is, someone presents a problem that a singular answer cannot completely solve, because the intent for the problem is not to collect a singular answer - it is meant to create a list of multiple "answers".</sup>
> >
> > ---
> >
> > <sup>Uso o termo "itemized list" para me referir a perguntas que não se encaixam nesse conceito. Ou seja, quando alguém apresenta um problema que nenhuma resposta única seria capaz de resolver, porque a intenção não é obter uma resposta, mas sim uma lista de múltiplas "respostas".</sup>

São conceitos bastante fluidos e repletos de casos complexos, como esse de agora. Interpretações divergentes vão existir e é um debate que dificilmente morrerá, pela impossibilidade de uma definição completa, objetiva e totalmente abrangente do que torna uma lista boa.

Ainda assim, acho que 2 pontos são muito válidos:

1. **Não há nada errado com listas**
   Podem repetir isso à exaustão. Não significa que não existem perguntas ruins. Significa apenas que usar *"pede uma lista"* como parâmetro de julgamento de uma pergunta é reducionista e incorreto.
2. **O que deve ser avaliado é o intuito e escopo da pergunta**
   Que problema o autor da pergunta quer solucionar? É possível fazer construir uma resposta válida e objetiva? O escopo da pergunta é muito grande? Muito pequeno? Não está dentro das regras do site? Ela pode ser útil à mais alguém?
   As listas ruins normalmente vão apresentar outros problemas que são mais fáceis de se identificar. E **isso** às torna não cabíveis no site. Se esses problemas puderem ser resolvidos com edições, mudando a apresentação do problema, prefiram isso à fechar a pergunta.

A resposta ficou enorme, mas acho que era preciso dissipar essa rejeição desnecessária às listas no site. Quanto à pergunta em questão, ela foi reaberta. O motivo de fechamento não fazia sentido e se ela vier a ser fechada novamente, que seja por algo mais correto.

Comment: Muito bacana sua análise e o *insight* da Grace. Tenho a impressão que muitos autores falham neste ponto específico: `Que problema o autor da pergunta quer solucionar?`. Tem vezes que nem com forceps dá pra extrair essa informação do AP.

Comment: @brasofilo Certamente. E isso é um problema grande porque o **problema**, e não a **pergunta**, é o que devemos avaliar para decidir se algo é cabível no site.

Comment: Ela foi fechada novamente *antes* de você postar esta resposta, como "baseada em opiniões". Entendo o motivo, parte do princípio de que qualquer *sugestão* de link será opinativa. A pergunta é um pedido de links, por isso não entendi por que você não considera uma *shopping question*. Na minha opinião é isso sim. Meu problema com ela não é que o conjunto das respostas é *uma lista*, e sim que ele é uma lista *de links*. O que sempre me atraiu nos sites da rede foi a qualidade das respostas, e respostas só com links para mim são de baixíssima qualidade (mesmo que a culpa seja da pergunta).

Comment: @bfavaretto São coisas diferentes, e devem ser tratadas de formas diferentes. Nem toda lista de link é opinativa, como não são no caso da pergunta. Ela **não é** baseada em opiniões. Quanto à qualidade de uma resposta contendo "apenas" links, isso também não é preto-no-branco como parece ser. De novo, não tenho interesse particular *nessa* pergunta, mas se forem fechá-la, que seja por um motivo e raciocínio adequado, não por uma aplicação estrita de uma regra que não existe.

Comment: Não vou estender a discussão porque entendo o que você quer dizer e até certo ponto acho válido (minhas discordâncias já devem estar mais ou menos claras nesta altura do campeonato). Mas quanto à pergunta específica, é um pedido de recomendação de site sobre aprendizado. Algo que (na minha opinião) é melhor procurar no Google, então por mim ela deveria ser fechada (mas não fecharei sozinho). E acho os dois motivos dos fechamentos anteriores válidos nesse caso – e por sinal nenhum deles é "pergunta de lista".

Comment: @Gabe, você usou seu voto privilegiado para reabrir a pergunta 2 vezes; minha leitura é que está claro que você vota com veemência por que ela permaneça aberta. E, nesse caso, uma edição *into shape* seria indicada para demonstrar seu ponto de vista de que aquela é uma pergunta adequada ao site. P.ex., o título da pergunta é completamente *misleading*... (com perdão do inglês, não lembro das palavras em português)

Comment: Gabe quando você abre a pergunta que a comunidade fechou (2x) está a passar por cima do voto de muita gente. Podia pelo menos, como o @brasofilo referiu, podia editar a pergunta para a melhorar. Talvez _isolar o problema da pergunta_ e trocar o link de um site externo por uma descrição do que o AP quer.

Comment: Concordo com o @Sergio. É uma pergunta baseada num link.

Comment: Já agora esta pergunta também deveria ser reaberta pelos mesmos critérios: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9889/programar-online-em-c

Comment: E se todos os links da resposta morressem?

Comment: Um título bom para a pergunta seria [Qual seu site favorito para exercícios em C#?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @brasofilo Não. Não seria. Há uma diferença muito grande entre pedir sites que possuam exercícios de C# e perguntar qual o seu *favorito*.

Comment: @Sergio Eu passei por cima de muita gente, e também defendi quase o mesmo número de pessoas. A pergunta tem upvotes e respostas de gente que, obviamente, aceita que a pergunta esteja ali. A opinião de quem fechou não vale mais, ou menos, do que a do resto. E **nesse caso** os dois motivos de fechamento, principalmente o segundo, eram incorretos.

Comment: @Gabe mas [nesse caso específico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/39415/revisions) não vejo ninguém a votar para abrir. Ou estou a interpretar mal o histórico?

Comment: @Sergio As pessoas que responderam ou votaram a favor deram tanta aprovação implícita quanto as pessoas que votaram para fechar deram reprovação implícita. E o número é quase o mesmo.

Comment: Sua matemática do contra vs a favor tá um pouco estranha... E fora que tem pelo menos 4 power users (40k+ na network) votando pelo fechamento. Dá a impressão que você adotou uma *shopping question* que pede uma "lista de links" só para provar a bonita teoria da Grace sobre "lista de items". Talvez seja o caso de avisar o Oded que o SOPT é o 4º site da rede que aceita Shopping Questions: [Are shopping recommendations off-topic or banned on every single Stack Exchange Site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243902/185667)

Comment: @brasofilo Isso é a [Falácia do Espantalho](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falácia_do_espantalho). E o [Argumentum ad verecundiam](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_verecundiam). Além de uma insinuação de que eu estou mentindo. Se metade do esforço em reprovar tudo que os "power users" discordam fosse gasto tentando *criar* maneiras de *melhorar* o site, esse tipo de caso não precisasse de um rebu tão grande.

Comment: @Gabe Não é o termo *favorito* que torna uma pergunta baseada em opinião. Ele não faz diferença nenhuma. Com esse argumento eu mesmo já removi o termo de várias perguntas e evitei o fechamento. Isso sem mudar a pergunta na essência, apenas tirando uma palavra que leva as pessoas a fecharem *cegamente*. Aqui o caso é outro, ninguém está agindo cegamente, basta ver quanta argumentação tem aqui neste debate.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu vi, até agora, uma preocupação razoável em relação à pergunta, que é a presença apenas de links. Eu também vi que apenas **uma** pessoa tentou fazer algo em relação à isso, movendo o conteúdo para a tag (como sugerido no Meta). O resto vem tentando argumentar pelo fechamento por motivos incorretos, como "baseado em opiniões". A pergunta não tem como ser mais objetiva. Eu não sei de que serve essa obsessão com o fechamento, como se isso fosse manter a qualidade do site alta.

Comment: @Gabe acho que votos positivos/negativos e votos abrir/fechar são coisas diferentes e não dá para motivar que votos positivos valem como votos para reabrir a pergunta. Curiosamente neste momento a pontuação da pergunta é `0` (+4 / -4) e o histórico mostra que 10 pessoas tentaram fechar ( e não podem votar de novo), você foi o unico a abrir (2x), acho incorreto.

Comment: Outra coisa que acho particularmente infeliz é você @Gabe dizer que os [power users deviam gastar mais tempo tentando criar maneiras de melhorar o site](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2226/perguntas-pedindo-indica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-ferramentas-online/2243?noredirect=1#comment7455_2243)... isto é exatamente o que esses users fazem e insunuar que metade do nosso tempo (sim eu incluo-me) não é a tentar melhorar o site acho falso e injusto.

Comment: @Sergio, talvez algo tenha se perdido na tradução. Não disse que votos para fechar e votos a favor são a mesma coisa. Não são. Disse que eles contam como aprovação/reprovação implícita. O total de pessoas fazendo um, ou outro, dá uma idéia de como a comunidade, no geral, se sente em relação à pergunta. E no caso dessa, o número de pessoas com ações de aprovação é quase o mesmo que o número de pessoas com ações de reprovação. Então não é justo dizer que a *comunidade* reprova a pergunta. A *comunidade* está dividida. E eu reabri a pergunta porque as razões de fechamento não eram cabíveis.

Comment: @Gabe o que eu acho que você falha é que você "desautoriza" os motivos dos membros da comunidade. Você diz agora: "as razões de fechamento não eram cabíveis". Ora entre os que votaram para fechar estão 2 dos quatro mais reputados membros do SOpt (eu incluído), um deles o nr.2 de C#. O nr.5 de C# também votou para fechar e o nr.1 de C# deixou [este comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39415/site-com-problemas-diversos-de-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o#comment80446_39415) que indica que o conteudo desta pergunta/resposta não deve estar ali mas nas tags da linguagem.

Comment: @Sergio Eu não quero que isso se torna ainda mais uma "discussão de internet em que ninguém se entende". Já expliquei N vezes porque a pergunta foi reaberta. Já li todas as disposições em contrário e nenhuma delas explica como a pergunta poderia ser "fora de escopo", muito menos "baseada em opiniões".

Comment: @Sergio Quanto à sua outra reclamação, "gastar metade do tempo [...]" é uma expressão comum no Brasil que não é levada literalmente (como muita coisa em PT_BR, alias... língua esquisita). Ela é interpretada como uma sugestão para uma mudança de foco, ou de abordagem, em relação a um problema. E isso eu continuo achando que deveria ter acontecido nesse caso. Isso não altera que me expressei mal e não levei em consideração as diferentes nacionalidades no site. Sinto muito por isso.

Comment: Eu sugeriria você estudar como o Shog faz intervenções em casos desse tipo, ou inclusive consultá-lo diretamente. Dica: "editar" o post problemático para mostrar "como é que se faz" é uma das principais características. . . Não era minha intenção sugerir que você mentiu, mas sim que se omitiu, atuou silenciosamente sem dar o exemplo para a comunidade de como é sua visão de que aquilo era uma boa pergunta.

Answer (score 10):

Quando você pergunta "manda um link aí de uma ferramenta que você gosta e acha que eu deveria usar" (claro que ninguém escreve com essas palavras, mas a pergunta é essa) ela é baseada em opiniões. As respostas só poderão ser dadas de acordo com a opinião de cada um, não dá para responder objetivamente. Há experiências nesses sentido que demonstram claramente que não é possível responder sem incorrer fortemente em opinião. Cada um um vai defender o que gosta. Ou pior, vai sugerir o que não conhece. O que você faz com essas indicações? Pode ir atrás e pesquisar. Mas isto não é diferente de ir no Google e fazer o mesmo. Aqui temos uma definição do que é uma resposta. E um link e quem sabe uma frase dizendo "usa que é bom" não responde nada.

Sempre que a pessoa for falar daquele *link* ela acaba sendo subjetiva. Ninguém consegue comprovar o que a pessoa está falando. No máximo terá pessoas com a mesma opinião. E a votação acaba se transformando em algo que deve classificar a qualidade em concurso de popularidade.

Claro que a definição do que é resposta é um pouco difícil de entender para quem não está acostumado com o site. O que é útil ou não é ainda mais complicado. Eu entendo que alguém pode achar um *link* útil. Ele é útil para facilitar você achar algo mas ele não dá nenhuma informação útil de fato, ele não responde a uma **pergunta**. Uma pergunta não é qualquer coisa que tenha um ponto de interrogação. Não é um pedido de ajuda qualquer. Uma pergunta deve ter um problema real que precisa ser resolvido. Esse problema pode ser conceitual mas precisa ter parâmetros, precisa indicar algum esforço de pesquisa anterior (esses pedidos de links costumam indicar justamente o contrário).

Indicar ferramentas é diferente de esclarecer um dúvida sobre ferramentas.

#### Mas o problema é da resposta

O software não deixa fechar respostas. Talvez devesse, não sei, mas o fato é que não deixa. Sempre foi considerado que é responsabilidade da pergunta "garantir" que as respostas sejam adequadas. Claro que alguém pode responder mal algo bem perguntado. Aí o problema é da resposta mesmo. O problema é que quase sempre a pergunta induz respostas ruins. E por isto a pergunta é fechada.

#### Recomendações

Não é que perguntas que pedem recomendações não devem ser aceitas mas elas precisam propiciar uma forma de produzir respostas boas, que respondam alguma coisa, que tenha parâmetros, que não produzam listas inúteis (listas úteis não seriam problema, mas em geral as listas não costumam ter essas características). A recomendação não pode cair no [Gorilla Vs Shark](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/488/gorilla-vs-shark). E não tem nada pior que me dá um *link* aí de algo genérico.

#### Somente links

Respostas que possuem somente *links* não agregam conteúdo ao site. Não somos repositórios de *links*. Em quase todos os *links* já postados aqui não há qualquer informação útil junto. Estas respostas normalmente atraem oportunistas que veem aquilo como uma forma fácil de ganhar reputação. São respostas que não demonstram esforço e não exigem o mínimo de comprometimento em produzir algo de qualidade. É o tipo de resposta que nos coloca como um simples fórum. É a resposta que pode ser obtida em qualquer lugar e pode ser dada por qualquer pessoa. É o tipo de bobagem que afasta as pessoas que prezam a qualidade.

E tem ainda os problemas já apresentados nas outras discussões e citados na pergunta. A própria pergunta acima mostra porque não podemos aceitar perguntas pedindo *links*. Elas podem gerar (e quase sempre geram) respostas sujeitas a problemas.

Link morto não significa apenas fora do ar. O conteúdo pode mudar e passar ser imprestável ao objetivo original da pergunta.

Eu acho um absurdo perguntas que só pedem *links*. Viu? Cada um tem uma opinião sobre isto. E acho pior respostas que se aproveitam disto.

Nós não temos perguntas que pedem *links*, elas são fechadas.

Há um histórico e até a SE que anda em uma cruzada (pelo menos por aqui) de aceitar coisas ruins admite que respostas só com links deveriam ser convertidas em comentários.

A SE às vezes quer mudar isto mas infelizmente não aponta para nenhuma mudança no software que possa permitir que a ferramenta seja mais adequada para isto. Ela até eliminou recursos que poderia até tornar este tipo de pergunta mais palatável. Ela evita fazer filtros reais nas perguntas para as pessoas se livrarem desse tipo de conteúdo que é indesejado.

Num mundo perfeito onde as pessoas agissem sempre buscando o melhor provavelmente esse tipo de restrição à pergunta não seria necessária porque aí todas as respostas seriam boas (não que seja fácil responder bem este tipo de coisa).

#### É consenso que não devemos aceitar respostas só com links

Não é unanimidade mas isto está bem estabelecido por todos os *sites* da rede.

#### Links podem morrer e não fornecem conteúdo relevante para o site

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Acho que nunca vi ninguém citar por aqui o artigo [Programming Is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://blog.codinghorror.com/programming-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), você já viu? Que eu saiba *Shopping Question* é defenestrada em toda rede...

Comment: Bem lembrado! O pessoal se esquece que este é um site de programação e não uma lista de compras. Embora acho que o link mais adequado neste caso seria http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: "Sempre foi considerado que é responsabilidade da pergunta "garantir" que as respostas sejam adequadas." - Neste caso, não é importante esclarecer isso na central de ajudas? Nem a seção "on topic" nem a seção "how to ask" dizem que perguntas pedindo links não são bem-vindas. A seção "don't ask" recomenda evitar pedir opiniões subjetivas, que discordo ser o caso dessas perguntas. Não seria o caso de incluir essa restrição em uma dessas seções (ou nas três)? Porque duvido muito que um usuário novo que tenha a pergunta fechada pelos motivos citados e sem comentário explicativo entenda o problema.

Comment: @kadu, as engrenagens do site funcionam um pouco a manivela. Quer dizer, *alguém* tem que pegar o touro pelo chifre; se possível, fazer uma pesquisa aqui e no [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) para montar a requisição; e finalmente abrir uma pergunta com um pedido de novo-recurso (ou bug) aqui no nosso Meta. Desse jeito, a pessoa (ou pessoas) responsável (community manager ou moderadores) fica com um "a-fazer registrado em cartório".

Comment: @kadu o fato de você discordar não faz essas perguntas serem objetivas. Você pedir algo que não pode ser comprovado se está certo é absolutamente subjetivo. Nas perguntas que você citou tem *links* que eu poderia dizer que é um crime a pessoa acessar. Quem está certo? É a minha opinião contra a de outra pessoa. Esta é a definição do subjetivo. Como saber se o *link* realmente ajuda? E se ele deixar de ajudar? E se (W3Schools) prejudicar? A central de ajuda não fala nada de perguntas porque a lógica deixa tácito quando indica que não pode em respostas. Mas por mim, podem colocar na central.

Comment: @brasofilo no caso, você recomenda que eu (ou alguém) faça essa pesquisa e crie a requisição para incluir esse ponto na central de ajuda?

Comment: @bigown não vejo como uma questão de opinião. Se um usuário pergunta ou pede um site capaz de fazer algo, os sites na resposta ou fazem o que o usuário pede, ou não fazem, não tem nada subjetivo. Para saber se o link ajuda ou não basta ver se a resposta foi aceita ou não, como é o caso com qualquer outra pergunta.

Comment: @bigown Mas concordo com você que se não é permitido responder com links não se deveriam fazer perguntas que peçam isso. Só acho que alguns usuários podem ter as questões fechadas, ler a página relevante da central de ajudas e não entender o problema (dado que a resposta estaria em "como responder", não em "como perguntar").

Comment: Ok, nós já entendemos que você discorda. Se fosse do jeito que você acha nem existiria o motivo de fechamento "baseado em opiniões". A pessoa aceita o que ela bem entender, ela pode aceitar uma resposta que diz "Java Sucks" e segundo sua opinião isto seria objetivo, isto resolveu o que o AP queria. As coisas não funcionam assim. Aí você já começou dizer que todo o sistema está errado. Boa sorte em tentar convencer todo mundo disto.

Comment: @kadu, foi um moderador do WPSE quem disse e eu repito sempre: "a missão do site é colecionar soluções, não links". Teve uma outra que não lembro quem foi e que é bem cáustica: "existe um site que é especialista nisso, você faz uma pergunta e ele te devolve uma lista de links". . . E, sim, concordo que falta oficializar isso aqui no SOpt.

Comment: @bigown você não parece ter entendido por que eu discordo, porque eu jamais falei o que você afirma. "Java sucks" é obviamente subjetivo: eu posso achar que sim, você que não. "O site X tem a funcionalidade Y" não é, não importa o que eu ou você pensemos dele. Você pode dizer que não é o tipo de pergunta que o site procura, mas chamar de subjetiva essa pergunta exige ignorar o que essa palavra significa.

Comment: Ok, já deu. A minha experiência nesses sites mostra o contrário.