# Por que duvidas baseadas em opiniões (trocar ideias) sobre códigos não são aceitas?

Tags: debate

Sou muito fã e uso bastante o `SoPT` e outras comunidades do `StackExchange`, já usei mais o `SoPT`. Eu fiz **[esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78273/como-deixar-esse-c%C3%B3digo-jquery-mais-profissional)** e teve uma ótima repercussão na comunidade pois todo mundo começou a se conversar e trocar ideias e pontos de vista de cada um (por mais que seja proibido expor suas ideias aqui) e isso me fez aprender e fez pessoas chegarem a um ponto de vista diferente porém válido de cada ideia passada para o uso de cada um.

O que aconteceu? **Fecharam a pergunta!!!**

Eu tenho uma dificuldade muito grande em entender o porquê de tesourar as pessoas que estão trocando ideias e aprendendo em cima mesmo dos comentários para absorver e aplicar os conhecimentos.

O absolutismo do ponto de vista de respeitar a risca as regras têm feito com que as pessoas cheguem cheias de vontade de estar aqui e comecem a fugir ao enfrentar esse tipo de situação de fechamento de perguntas ou mesmo comentários indelicados de usuários que sabem um pouco mais aumentando assim o índice de usuários inativos, aumentando índices de falta de votos ou comentários, de participação de forma geral na comunidade.

Afinal, é pra participar ou não? É pra interagir com as pessoas ou simplesmente perguntar ou responder como se fossemos o **Google**?

Comment: Porque este é um site de Q&A e não um fórum. O conceito do site é mesmo esse, perguntas objetivas e repostas objetivas. (estou a responder a pergunta de uma forma geral, já que nem abri a tua pergunta). 
A ideia é mesmo termos aqui informação para ajudar a comunidade de programadores. E não para discutir assuntos.

Comment: Mas eu tenho certeza que você sabe que este conceito influencia um elevado número de desistências, de inatividade de usuários na comunidade, pessoas novas sentem medo de estar aqui.

Comment: Eu sei que somos um povo que presa muito pela interatividade entre pessoas. Mas a verdade é que a ideia do site é ter perguntas e respostas de qualidade. E não debates sobre assuntos, mesmo que estes sejam interessantes.

Comment: Claro que eu sei, mas isso é um ponto negativo no meio de milhares de pontos positivos deste tipo de site, basta ver o sucesso de quase todos os sites da SE.

Comment: O que você está falando @JorgeB. é que temos que respeitar 100% o regulamento ou somos "punidos" e não existe nada na vida que se pode afirmar a integridade a 100% exceto o SoPT :)

Comment: Cuidado que eu estou a responder sem ver a pergunta, porque acho que a sua pergunta é mais geral e serve para muita gente que venha a ter a mesma dúvida/pensamento.

Comment: Não, estou a dizer que este site é um site de Q&A e não é um fórum, só isso.

Comment: Você @JorgeB. é um cara muitoooo inteligente e ativo na comunidade e já me ajudou muito, tenho certeza que sabe do que está falando. O fato é: tem que ser exatamente assim?

Comment: Você tem 164 perguntas, pelo que eu vi você só tem 5 fechadas (sem considerar as duplicadas) e uma por fechar agora. Sua chateação se dá pela proporção de perguntas fechadas no site ou com a pergunta em questão? Ou tem a ver com algum outro ponto do site que você não deixou claro aqui?

Comment: Se você usa outras comunidades da SE , sabe que aqui é a mais maleável. A troca de ideias, pontos de vista (outro nome para opinião), conversar, é justamente o que não se faz nos sites da SE. Eu nem olhei a pergunta, estou falando só baseado no que você escreveu aqui. Justamente por controlar o conteúdo, aqui é melhor que os fóruns. Se liberar tudo, fica tão ruim quanto os lugares ruins que as pessoas aprendem errado. Objetivamente aqui é para perguntar, responder e votar. Secundariamente sinalizar, editar, comentar para ajudar o conteúdo melhorar, não para discutir o assunto. O resto é ruído.

Comment: @Math o meu ponto de vista leva em consideração  de forma geral as pessoas que chegam no site. Essas pessoas muitas vezes chegam para conhecer e aprender. Quando elas têm uma pergunta fechada, elas devem se sentir tristes, magoadas, frustradas porque nem todos sabem lidar com isso.

Comment: "Como eu poderia deixar esse código abaixo mais profissional?" Como é que se pode responder a isso sem se basear em opiniões? Se me conseguires explicar...

Comment: Acho que o problema da sua questão está no título `Como tornar o código mais profissional?`, pergunta meio "ampla" demais, e subjetiva, talvez `Tem como melhorar esse código?` ou algo do tipo resolva, mas vamos aguardar, se fechar basta apenas editar e tentar abrir.

Comment: Mas gostavas que fosse permitido perguntas baseadas em opiniões é isso?

Comment: Eu adoraria que o SOpt fosse mais perto dos 100% de integridade, mas está tão, mas tão longe disto. Quem quer discutir assuntos, tem que ir em outro local mesmo, aqui não foi feito para isto. Quando a pessoa quiser respostas objetivas e controladas pela comunidade, não há lugar melhor que aqui. Ainda que poderia ser melhor se fosse mais íntegro. Você só está bravo porque sua pergunta não foi aceita. E novamente, não vi se ela deve ou não, estou falando do que está acontecendo aqui. É melhor para todos quando cuidamos da comunidade mais do que o indivíduo. Fórum é melhor para o indivíduo.

Comment: Acho que poderíamos deixar que a pergunta fosse respondida, aceita e esquecida. Se realmente houvesse uma demasiada extensão do assunto, poderia analisar em fechá-la mas não fechá-la 10 minutos da pergunta no ar @JorgeB.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius mas se uma pergunta não está dentro das regras do site tem de ser fechada, a meu ver, para não começarem a chover respostas fracas. Não estou a dizer que é o caso. Senão abre-ri-a-mos precedentes para bate-papo em perguntas e respostas.

Comment: Tudo que não estou é bravo @bigown estou só pensado pelos outros que não se lançam a vir aqui perguntar porque suas perguntas foram fechadas com receio de serem acoados.

Comment: Eu não discordo das regras da comunidade pessoal, só acho que deveriam ser um pequeno pouco mais flexíveis. Já vi aqui o cara que se registrou na comunidade e a primeira pergunta foi fechada. O que vocês acham que essa pessoa faz? Vai embora e não volta nunca mais. Claro que isso é um caso em centenas ou milhares de perguntas.

Comment: Acabei de ver a pergunta, ele recebeu diversas respostas, o que já é um indicativo de problemas (só indicativo, não vi detalhes e não sei se fecharia ela). Uma resposta já foi aceita. Pronto, agora podemos esquecê-la, como você disse? Podemos fechar aqui também? Se é para esquecer, é melhor não ficar falando nela. Para perguntar coisas que não vão agregar nada real e objetivo, é melhor não ter essas pessoas. Queremos que elas apareçam aqui para ter **respostas**, não **discussões** e **opiniões**. A pessoa ficar triste, acoada, magoada é algo pessoal, não podemos cuidar dos seus sentimentos.

Comment: Tudo bem @bigown !!! Se querem levar assim que seja assim. Só uma coisa que eu não sei se você sabe: o edifício é feito pra balançar com adversidades climáticas e se ele não balança, uma hora ele cai. #ficaadica

Comment: Acho que nesse caso, o problema está na própria palavra "profissional".
Existem muitas maneiras de ser profissional.... dizer que um código é mais profissional que outro é se basear em opinião....

Comment: Quando ele é feito de areia ele nem fica em pé. O SO existe há 7 anos e se transformou no maior site de programação do mundo, com larga folga justamente pelo material que é feito, não por ser de outra forma. Repeito, estamos aqui para responder sobre programação, não para cuidar de sentimentos, não para discutir, não para gastar tempo em fazer a pergunta ser respondível (embora alguns aqui acham que deveria ser assim, mas vai contra todos os sites da rede). Aqui tem muita flexibilidade. Mais do que deveria ter. Você quer que ela tenha a flexibilidade da areia, aí é ruim.

Comment: @JorgeB. acho que a pergunta é sobre revisão de código sim, mas está faltando algumas coisas na pergunta(sopt), agora o que está rolando nos comentários é outra coisa e até parece mais importante que a própria pergunta(meta). Se der um tempo eu respondo...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento só o AP sabe o que realmente quer. Eu parece-me que ele está a discutir aqui é as perguntas de debate e opinião e não revisão de código, embora esteja presente na pergunta do AP:

Comment: @rray veja meu comentário ^^^^^^

Comment: @MarcosVinicius podes esclarecer aqui qual é o teu objetivo?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Pelo seu comentário **" poderia analisar em fechá-la mas não fechá-la 10 minutos da pergunta no ar "** percebi que você acha que fechar é algo definitivo, mas está enganado, não é isto, fechar tem o proposito de por exemplo "prevenir respostas" quando a pergunta ainda não se adéque, ela pode ser reaberta a qualquer momento, leia isto: [Votos para fechar perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635) - perguntas Suspensas não são perguntas Banidas e nem Deletadas, são perguntas que podem ser editadas e reabertas **se necessário**!!

Comment: @MarcosVinicius na verdade, quando uma pergunta é fechada aparece o "motivo" pelo qual foi fechada, vide: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4484/como-fazer-multi-upload-de-imagens-no-codeigniter , bem como quem votou em fecha-la. Em casos do AQ ficar na dúvida do motivo do fechamento, os comentários servem para que votou em fechar explicar o motivo do voto, como é feito na maioria das vezes

Comment: Apaguei o comentário sobre motivos, você tem razão que as informações aparecem @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: A pergunta não foi fechada ainda, muito menos foi em 10 minutos. Então o AP está jogando palavras ao vento e não argumentando. Note que o tempo todo eu não falei da pergunta em questão. Falei apenas da desnecessidade desta pergunta aqui no meta. Isto é assunto que já foi debatido diversas vezes. EM geral novas perguntas deste tipo sãoo apenas *rant* ou *venting*.

Comment: Perguntas sobre como melhorar um código, como essa sua, [são aceitas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1510/74). Já tem várias desse tipo, e tem até uma tag: [tag:revisão-código]. Agora, sobre perguntas que não são perguntas e sim debates/bate-papos, não. Aqui no meta somos bem mais flexíveis com debates, mas esta própria pergunta sua e a quantidade de comentários embaixo dela já mostram como a ferramenta não é boa para esse tipo de coisa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como o bigown bem apontou, a pergunta não foi fechada. Isso é importante. Ela recebeu sim votos para fechar, mas não chegaram a ter número suficiente. Talvez aconteça no futuro, mas no momento ela continua aberta - corretamente, ao meu ver.

A necessidade de 5 votos é justamente para evitar que algum radical mal-humorado saia atazanando e fechando o post dos outros. É uma maneira de pesar as diferentes opiniões e tentar chegar a algo que seja razoavelmente parecido com um consenso. Não é perfeito, mas resolve a maioria dos casos.

Dito isso, realmente não tem muito motivo da discussão existir, já que não existe o problema... Mas acho que um ponto importante pode ser levantado.

**Por que essa pergunta recebeu 4 votos para fechar?**

Os votos na pergunta e respostas são avassaladoramente favoráveis, ela obteve participação em massa. O tema é interessante, dentro do escopo e perfil do site. Mas ainda assim, 4 votos para fechar - sendo 1 retirado mais tarde.

Uma edição de *uma palavra* foi capaz de "resgatar" a pergunta, com um dos votos para fechar sendo até removido. Isso é um problema.

Se 1 palavra é a diferença entre manter a pergunta ou fechá-la, é porque a pergunta nunca teve problema algum.

Eu já [falei antes](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2243/12) que **"O que deve ser avaliado é o intuito e escopo da pergunta"**. Que problema essa pergunta apresenta? Quais são as soluções possíveis? 1 palavra nunca devia ser suficiente para alterar isso a ponto de resgatar uma pergunta do fechamento.

Comment: Não concordo contigo @Gabe uma palavra pode fazer toda a diferença. Alias uma palavra no sitio errado pode ser a diferença de estar vivo ou de estar morto em alguns sítios no mundo. Eu li a pergunta vezes sem conta antes de por para fechar, isto antes deste post (fui eu que retirei o voto). Pareceu-me sempre que a pergunta estava baseada em opiniões. Depois de retirar a tal palavra, já vi a pergunta de forma completamente diferente. Poderá ser problema meu, não sei.

Comment: Fui reler e continuo a achar "Como deixar esse código jQuery mais profissional?" baseada em opiniões.

Comment: @JorgeB. Julgo que pensas assim porque consideradas que o conceito de *"mais profissional"* pode ser uma questão de opinião. Se traduzires *"mais profissional" por *"seguir as boas práticas aceites"* talvez mudes de opinião. Como muito bem diz o Gabe *"O que deve ser avaliado é o intuito e escopo da pergunta"* e não o facto de sabermos que há "profissionais" que escrevem código de fraca qualidade.

Comment: @ramaral não é por isso. É mesmo por achar que "deixar o código mais profissional" é muito vago. Também não gosto muito dessa das boas práticas. Gosto de "deve se fazer isto porque aquilo" o resto é opinião.

Comment: @ramaral tipo "Como melhorar esse código jQuery?" Será que eu posso melhorar o código? Como? Porque é que é melhor que o meu?.

Comment: @ramaral  se calhar têm razão, mas acho que como estava dava asas a respostas de "acho que" do que como está agora. A pergunta agora está "mais profissional" ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Nota que eu tive o cuidado de acrescentar a palavra "aceites" a "boas práticas", se analisares qualquer código à luz "das boas práticas aceites" nunca é uma questão de opinião.

Comment: @JorgeB. Quando encontrei a pergunta, na fila de análise, também tive dúvidas em como a classificar e optei por "pular".  Em relação às resposta começadas por "Acho que", é votar negativo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Esse seu exemplo "Como melhorar? ... Por que?" é justamente o ponto da resposta do Gabe. Se a pergunta pode ser reformulada assim, a primeira coisa a fazer é editar e salvá-la, em vez de votar para fechar.

Comment: @bfavaretto mas isso não é alterar a intenção do autor?

Comment: @JorgeB. Não. Volta pra mesma idéia de avaliar a *intenção* da pergunta. Todas as pessoas que votaram e responderam antes da edição entenderam a intenção da pergunta, e todas as respostas continuam válidas após a edição, porque ela não alterou o sentido original, apenas a forma como ele foi apresentado.

Comment: @Gabe se calhar têm razão.