# Dúvida de perguntas sobre indicação de plugins e afins

Tags: debate

Estou com uma dúvida.

Estou a procura de algum plugin Jquery, que eu consiga fazer diagramas, para ser utiliza em um projeto C# MVC.

Exemplos de plugins que busco:

http://resources.jointjs.com/demos/kitchensink

https://drive.draw.io/

E não sei aonde posso perguntar isto. É aqui? ou melhor como perguntar?

Comment: Isso não se encaixa bem no site principal e tampouco no meta, talvez o lugar mais apropriado seria o [chat]. Relacionado: [Perguntas pedindo indicação de ferramentas online](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2226/3117)

Comment: A pergunta não se enquadra no [escopo do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Pergunta fora de foco com +3. Como diz o Faustão: "_Ô locco meu!_"