# Negativado em resposta aceita como correta, qual é o critério?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, voto-contra

Fui negativado na pergunta [Servidor de streaming.. Ouvir/Baixar/Upload de Áudio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89586/servidor-de-streaming-ouvir-baixar-upload-de-%C3%81udio/89599#comment181087_89599)

Mas não tinha mais o que falar e o usuário agradeceu bastante. Como revisar isso? Invalida minha resposta mas pode ser útil mais para frente e não tinha muito mais o que falar.

Se escrevesse mais seria desnecessário já que o projeto nem é meu.

Comment: A pergunta do AP não segue o padrão das perguntas do SOpt, e como o Jorge B disse nos comentários, os links que vc  postou não garantem que vão ficar online. O objetivo do SOpt é ter uma base contento soluções para diversos problemas na área de desenvolvimento de software. O melhor seria o AP dividir o problema  e fazer perguntas que se baseiam em algo pratico.

Comment: Não que seja errado postar links, mas, no meu ponto de vista vc deveria te indicado os links na área exclusiva para comentário, eu costumo fazer desta forma, porem fica a critério do autor da resposta.

Comment: Sua dúvida é válida, mas para esclarecer, aprovação de quem perguntou e do resto da comunidade são coisas isoladas. O "accept" ( **✓** ) é um sinal de que você  ajudou o autor, e isto é ótimo. Entretanto, a votação da comunidade indica que algo não está adequado na resposta. Veja isto como um "filtro" do site, e não como uma repreensão pessoal.

Comment: Olhando a resposta, eu vejo que ela realmente poderia ser melhor elaborada, assim como o fato de depender de links complica um pouco a "durabilidade" da resposta. Lembre-se que você pode editá-la a qualquer momento, nem que seja ao menos para por um breve resumo do que se referem os tais links. E quando você edita uma postagem, ela volta para o começo da fila de postagens ativas recentemente, ganhando novas visualizações. Se a edição melhorar o conteúdo, tem grande chance de atrair novos votos, e desta vez, positivos. Talvez até quem negativou, reverta o voto, caso perceba a melhoria.

Comment: Perguntas bacanas pra responder (troque pela tag de sua preferência): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50

Comment: Eu achei a resposta válida, mas ao mesmo tempo a pergunta foge do escopo de perguntas aceitas.

Comment: Eu fui negativado aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109197/m%C3%BAltipla-sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-funciona-no-ie, a questão é que eu havia antes feita uma pergunta e postei os códigos. Acontece que a pergunta que fiz, recebi a resposta e precisei fazer uma outra em cima dos mesmos códigos. Como eu não poderia pedir duas resposta na mesma pergunta, abri outro post e para minha surpresa, 3 downvotes. O que deduzo é porque os códigos são os mesmos e a segunda pergunta é sutilmente diferente. Não há interpretação.Ninguém se dá, às vezes, "ao luxo" de ler e entender o post. Downvote!!

Answer (score 14):

Basicamente você topou com dois problemas, respondeu uma pergunta que é descaradamente [fora de escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) e publicou uma resposta que é basicamente "só link". Pode conferir porque são consideradas respostas de baixa qualidade neste tópico do FAQ:

- **[Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links)**

Aquele comentário do Jorge B. na sua resposta é um "comentário enlatado". O sistema detecta automaticamente respostas que podem ser "só-link" e também podemos sinalizar essas respostas como de baixa qualidade:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Quando isso acontece (detecção automática ou sinalização), a resposta vai para uma fila de análise onde podemos votar para deletar. Ao votar, temos a opção do comentário enlatado. Ou seja, o Jorge nem escreveu aquilo, só clicou "votar pra deletar e mostrar um comentário de justificativa".

<strike>Perguntas fechadas, com votos negativos e sem respostas votadas positivamente são deletadas automaticamente em X tempo (não lembro qual)</strike> <sup>(parece que ter uma resposta aceita impede a deleção automática: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/185667))</sup>. Usuários com alta reputação também podem votar para deletar sem nem passar por fila de análise, então tem chance daquele par Pergunta/Resposta virarem fumaça...

E fumaça também serão os +15 pontos que ganhou por ter a resposta aceita. Bom, mas também recupera os -2 do voto negativo, saldo -13 :)
Mas isso só se a pergunta for mesmo deletada antes de 60 dias <sup>(vide *What else should I know about deleted posts?* do FAQ do Meta.SE linkado acima)</sup>, se for deletada depois, a pontuação atual permanece. Deletar a pergunta leva com ela a resposta.

Se estou entendendo bem o FAQ, a resposta pode ser deletada por 3 votos de usuários com mais de 20k de reputação ou por 6 votos na fila de análise de posts baixa qualidade.

Ninguém é obrigado a comentar sobre seu voto, positivo ou negativo, e o voto é secreto. Essas duas características do site são imutáveis.