# Referências Externas

Tags: suporte

bom dia! Estou começando a ajudar a comunidade no stackoverflow em português e fiquei com a seguinte dúvida:

Quando vamos citar referência de outros sites, é necessário incluir o conteúdo ou somente o link?

Existe algum problema em colar a resposta de uma outra pergunta e deixar o link como referência?

Quais seriam as boas práticas para este tipo de cenário?

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Incluir o conteúdo é diferente de colocar um link. Se você "colar" de maneira "descarada" a resposta de outra pergunta (até outro site) vai passar uma imagem ruim. Tente escrever com suas próprias palavras com base em outra resposta ou conteúdo, isso sim vai ajudar muita gente :)

Comment: Relacionado: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/53279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Só *link* não é bem visto e em geral é considerado apropriado apenas como comentário, o conteúdo precisa estar aqui, porque o original pode ser mudado ou removido e aí a resposta fica inválida. Tem até uma sinalização para os usuários indicarem que aqui é **só** *link* e é usada mesmo que tenha alguma texto que só está enchendo linguiça e não produz conteúdo algum.

Mas trazer o conteúdo do *link* em *copy & paste*, também não é o ideal ou até é totalmente inadequado.

Muito do conteúdo na internet, ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, não pode ser copiado, mesmo com a citação do local. Se não está explicitamente dito que pode copiar, então não pode. No máximo pode fazer uma citação de um pequeno trecho para ajudar fundamentar a **sua** resposta. Isto é uso justo.

Mesmo que se permita copiar, só copiar não é bem visto pela comunidade, ainda que permitido. Eu evitaria na maioria dos casos, principalmente em coisas conceituais, mas vai de cada um. Sempre cite a fonte, mesmo quando não é obrigado.

Escreva com suas próprias palavras, é muito melhor.

Mas tem outra coisa. Se você está copiando uma resposta já dada em outra pergunta aqui no site, é quase certo que a pergunta é duplicata, e deveria votar, se tiver reputação para isto, ou sinalizar para fechar a fechamento. Não tem porque ficar espalhando mesmas respostas por todo o site.

Comment: +1 *"Se você está copiando uma resposta **já dada em outra pergunta aqui no site**, é quase certo que a pergunta é duplicata, e deveria votar, se tiver reputação para isto, ou sinalizar para fechar a fechamento."*

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mesmo sendo do SO em en-US?

Comment: @miltoncamara **já dada em outra pergunta AQUI no site**, SOpt != SOen, sites diferentes, comunidades diferentes, só seguem o mesmo ideal, mas não são o mesmo site.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento agora ficou totalmente claro! :) Muito obrigado!