# Uma resposta curta deve ser apagada?

Tags: debate

Nessa pergunta o usuário não soube especificar muito bem que queria um recurso de macros em Python: [Tem como substituir comandos por variaveis no python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295500/tem-como-substituir-comandos-por-variaveis-no-python/295503)

Expliquei qual recurso ele estava buscando e coloquei o link de uma biblioteca que implementa o recurso, e em menos de 24 horas minha resposta foi apagada.

[image: print do comentario apagado]

A questão é: minha resposta deveria ter sido apagada porque "devia ter sido um comentário", mesmo apontando para (mais de uma) solução possível para o problema?

Ou, vendo de outra forma: vocês acham que a moderação correr assim para apagar respostas é a melhor forma de lidar com isso? Se a resposta é "ruim", ou "parcial", ou "apenas contém links", os próprios usuários do site não podem votar nela (pra cima ou pra baixo)?

Além disso, se alguém comentou que a resposta está fraca, eu mesmo poderia voltar lá depois de um tempo e incrementar a resposta, colocar um exemplo de código, para ver se ela sobe de pontuação, etc.

Se o objetivo dos moderadores é melhorar a qualidade das respostas, não é apagando a resposta que vai melhorar. Acredito que esse tipo de comportamento dos moderadores só desestimula e afasta os usuários que estão começando a contribuir com respostas.

Pesquisei nas [guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) do StackOverflow em inglês, e pra mim isso não está nem um pouco alinhado com o que eles defendem:

> What NOT To Flag:
>
> Any post that attempts to answer the question—however
>   badly—is still an answer! Do not use the "not an answer" flag for
>   wrong answers. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of
>   answers.
>
> You can downvote such answers as a signal that they are bad answers
>   and not useful, but they are still answers, so you should not flag them.

Comment: Perceba que o trecho citado refere-se à moderação explicitamente, mas o que ocorreu foi pela própria comunidade. Eu indiquei que a resposta seria melhor como comentário baseando-me na discussão [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/5878) E já que vitou o SOen, outro link interessante será o [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/5878). Não concordo como a exclusão da resposta ocorreu; ao meu ver, ela deveria ter sido convertida para comentário pela moderação.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Em vez de me pedir para reduzir a resposta a um comentário, porque você não me pediu para ampliar a resposta e deixá-la mais relevante? Não seria esse o objetivo do site?

Comment: Sim, seria uma alternativa melhor. O meu comentário foi no sentido de, se é para indicar o nome de uma ferramenta, basta comentar na pergunta. Isso é uma informação não complementar, não uma resposta. Mas com certeza, se estiver disposto, será muito melhor, de fato, se incorporar na resposta o principal conteúdo do link, deixando-o apenas como uma referência complementar.

Comment: O que eu estou questionando é exatamente essa atitude: criticar as respostas, tentar reduzi-las a comentários, apagá-las em menos de 24h... Até agora não recebi nenhum comentário construtivo dos usuários mais antigos do site. Já vieram até criticar performance da solução (oi??), e acabei tendo que testar e mostrar que meu código era 1000x mais rápido que o dele. Se aqui não é o StackOverflow, realmente não parece ser...

Comment: Acho que deu a interpretação errada ao que foi comentado na resposta. Repare que ninguém votou negativo na sua resposta, apenas indicaram que da forma que estava (inicial) era quase só um link, e por esse motivo ou deveria passar a ser um comentário, ou ser detalhada acrescentando informações relevantes. É relevante de indicar que se a resposta se baseia num link ou não é um pouco subjetivo, podendo certamente pender para uma analise errada em alguns casos. Pessoalmente acho que inicialmente era passivel de ser "só um link" mas nesta ultima versão considero uma resposta não baseada em link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu tinha até convertido em comentário antes de ver isto. Mas analisando melhor de fato responde a pergunta.

Ela é curta, simples, tem um *link*. Mas não é só um *link*, responde a questão. Nem vou entrar no mérito se está correta ou não, se poderia ser melhor, isto eu não sei, mas sei que é uma resposta. Está de volta.

Alguém discorda?

Baixa qualidade é discutível, mas faria mais sentido que "não é resposta".

> Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is still an answer!

Isto indica que é resposta, mas não que a qualidade seja baixa, ou esteja errada. O que daria negativo.

Infelizmente muitos recursos são mal usados, até mesmo nós moderadores nem sempre fazemos certo porque não há regras claras. Deveria ter mais critério de quem pode fazer certas ações no site. tem muito voto (no sentido amplo) errado no site que faz a credibilidade geral cair. Inclusive sei de muita gente que não gosta e não usa o site por causa disto.

Comment: Obrigado, Maniero! Se outros usuários acharem a qualidade baixa e votarem por isso, paciência, mas ao menos existe lá uma alternativa para quem quiser fazer algo parecido em Python. Remover como "não é uma resposta" não é uma resposta. :)

Comment: Eu não votei nessa questão, mas acho que eu e outros usuários estão acostumados a ver uma resposta, sem código e com um link e nem prestar muita atenção. Marca como "não é resposta". Mas a resposta é "use uma macro" e o link para o pacote que simula a macro. A resposta é ruim, se tivesse um exemplo de como implementar uma macro, ficaria boa. Não deveria ter sido apagada. Mas acho que eu teria marcado para apagar, por engano, mesmo sem merecer.

Comment: @MarcosBanik não coloquei exemplo porque a biblioteca parece bem complicada de usar. De qualquer forma, como a resposta já foi restabelecida, dei uma expandida lá nas possibilidades de solução.