# Usar documentação como resposta

Tags: debate, respostas

Posso usar a documentação de um framework ou linguagem como respostas ?

Pois muitas documentações, tem textos bem explicativos e com exemplos.

Comment: Procurei mas não encontrei aqui no Meta, provavél duplicata.

Comment: Provavemente se aparecer um caso em que isso é adequado, é indicativo de que a pergunta talvez deva ser fechada (ou no minimo negativada). Nâo que não possamos explicar coisa que o manual explica, mas tem que ter um problema real na postagem além de acomodação do autor.

Comment: @Bacco por isso que eu falo que tem coisa que pode ter uma "resposta" ao que foi postado, só não uma oficial, quando a resposta é sim ou não, é um *link*, ou algo tão simples assim, não tem porque ter respostas oficial, por isso fecha, mas ajudar a pessoa pode, no comentário.

Comment: Eu tenho uma dúvida. Se eu achar a resposta completa, daquela pergunta feita, em um link, eu poderia só deixar o link do site, em que eu encontrei a resposta, nos comentários ? Teria problemas "linkar" sites dessa maneira ? Se for uma resposta que eu achei no Github, por exemplo ...

Comment: Não vejo problema se for nos comentários, acredito que faz sentido, caso não queira formular uma resposta sua.

Comment: Formular ? Na verdade seria só copiar o conteúdo do outro site e colocar ali na resposta. Estou comentando isso pq esses dias isso aconteceu comigo. Fiz uma pergunta e o rapaz respondeu. A resposta me serviu e beleza. Sendo que depois eu continuei a olhar pela internet e encontrei um site que tinha aquele mesmo conteúdo da resposta do rapaz (mas era exatamente todo conteúdo mesmo, sem nada a mais ou a menos). Então fiquei pensando sobre isso...

Answer (score 10):

Não. Pode usar como complemento, como fundamentação, mas a resposta deve estar no site, tudo o que é o foco da pergunta deve ser com seu texto e responder efetivamente ali na postagem. Para a pessoa ir além do que foi perguntando no assunto, para estudar mais um *link* para a documentação e outras fontes é bem útil, inclusive para a pessoa validar por conta própria o respondeu.

Se a licença da documentação permitir pode copiar uma parte do conteúdo de lá, mas evite abusar disto, tente explicar com suas palavras, não somos um site pra reproduzir documentações. Citações são úteis, mas não deixe ficar nisto.

Isto é importante para a pessoa não ter que ficar procurando em qual parte da documentação está a resposta, para facilitar o SEO e sua resposta ser melhor achada e para evitar que o *link* deixe de ser válido (ou porque sumiu, ou porque mudou de lugar).

Veja mais em [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/101).